# Division of Factorials [binomal coefficients are integers]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial, multinomial-coefficients

I have a partition of a positive integer $(p)$. How can I prove that the factorial of $p$ can always be divided by the product of the factorials of the parts?

As a quick example $\frac{9!}{(2!3!4!)} = 1260$ (no remainder), where $9=2+3+4$.

I can *nearly* see it by looking at factors, but I can't see a way to guarantee it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The key observation is that the product of $n$ consecutive integers is divisible by $n!$. This can be proved by induction.

Comment: A quicker proof than induction would be to note that (by definition) $\binom{k}{n}$ is an integer, hence $n!|k\cdot (k-1)\ldots (k-n+2)\cdot (k-n+1)$.

Comment: Is that because given n (or more) consecutive integers one of them will always be divisible by n?

Answer (score 70):

Below is a sketch of a little-known *purely arithmetical* proof that binomial coefficients are integral. I purposely constructed the proof so that it would be comprehensible to an educated layperson. The proof gives an algorithm to rewrite a binomial coefficient as a product of fractions whose denominators are coprime to any given prime. The method of proof is  best comprehended by applying the algorithm to a specific example [**Note:** It may prove helpful to first read [this simpler example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5829) before proceeding to the exposition below].

E.g. $ $ consider $\  \binom{39}{17}\, =\, \frac{39!}{22!\, 17!}\, =\, \frac{23 \cdot 24 \cdots\; 39}{1 \cdot 2 \cdots\; 17}.\, $ When this fraction is reduced to lowest terms $\rm\:a/b,\, $ no prime $\rm\ p > 17\ $ can divide its denominator $\rm\: b,\: $ since $\rm\ b\:|\:17\:!\ \:$ Hence, to show that $\rm\ a/b\ $ is an integer, it suffices to show that no prime $\rm\ p \le 17\ $ divides its denominator $\rm\: b$.

E.g. we show that $\,2\,$ doesn't divide $\rm b$. The highest power of $\,2\,$ in the
denominator terms is $16 < 17$. *Align* the numerators & denominators $\!\bmod 16\,$ by shifting the 1st numerator term so it lies above its value $\!\bmod 16,\,$
viz. $\,\color{#c00}{23 \equiv 7} \pmod{\!16}\,$ so right-shift the numerator terms until $\,23\,$ lies above $\:\!7\,$

$$\color{#0a0}{\frac{}{1}\frac{}{2}\frac{}{3}\frac{}{4}\frac{}{5}\frac{}{6}}\color{#c00}{\frac{23}{7}}\frac{24}{8}\frac{25}{9}\frac{26}{10}\frac{27}{11}\frac{28}{12}\frac{29}{13}\frac{30}{14}\frac{31}{15}\frac{32}{16}\frac{33}{17}\color{#0a0}{\frac{34}{}\frac{35}{}\frac{36}{}\frac{37}{}\frac{38}{}\frac{39}{}}$$

We claim that $\,2\,$ does not divide the reduced denominator of each aligned fraction. Indeed $\ 24/8 = 3$, $\: 26/10 = 13/5 $,  $\:\ 28/12 = 7/3 $,  $\:\ 30/14 = 15/7 $,  $\:\ 32/16 = 2$.
This holds because these fractions $\rm\; c/d \;$  satisfy  $\,\rm c \equiv d\ (mod\ 16)\:$
i.e.  $\,\rm c = d + 16\:\! n \;$  so  $\,\rm 2|d \Rightarrow 2|c$, $\rm\; 4|d \Rightarrow 4|c$, $\:\cdots $, $\rm\; 16|d \Rightarrow 16|c,\,$
i.e. any power of $2\:$ below $16$ dividing $\rm d$ must divide $\rm c$, so it cancels out of $\rm\,c/d$.

Therefore to prove that $2$ doesn't divide the reduced denominator of $\binom{39}{17}$
it suffices to prove the same for the "leftover" fraction $\,\color{#0a0}{(34 \cdots 39)/(1 \cdots 6) = \binom{39}{6}}\,$ composed
of the above non-aligned terms. Being an $\rm\binom{n}{k}$ with smaller $\rm k = 6 < 17,\,$ this follows by induction.

Since the same proof works for any prime $\rm p$, we conclude that no prime divides the
reduced denominator of $\,\binom{39}{17},\,$ therefore it is an integer.$\quad$ **QED**

Informally, the reason that this works is because the denominator sequence starts at $1$, which is coprime to every prime $\rm p$. This ensures that it is the "greediest" possible contiguous sequence of integers, in the sense that its product contains the least power of $\rm\:p\:$ compared to other contiguous sequences of equal length.

The algorithm extends to multinomials by using the simple reduction of multinomials to products of binomials mentioned in my prior post here.

Comment: As elegant as it is, this proof strikes me as requiring more mathematical sophistication than does the standard combinatorial proof of $\binom{n}{k}\in\mathbb{N}$.  This makes me wonder how many "purely arithmetic" proofs of divisibility in number theory can be reduced to simpler combinatorial arguments.

Comment: @BillDubuque Neat! (+1) As a layperson, shall I refer to this as the 'Dubuque method of shifts' in my notebook? :}

Answer (score 61):

The "high-level" way to see this is to recall that whenever a finite group $G$ has a subgroup $H$, we know that $|H|$ divides $|G|$.  Then note that $S_n$ clearly contains $S_{n_1} \times ... \times S_{n_k}$ as a subgroup for any partition $n_1 + ... + n_k = n$.  (This is actually the same as the combinatorial interpretation in Robin Chapman's answer, since what we are counting is the number of cosets $G/H$, and these cosets are precisely what the multinomial theorem is counting.)

This basic lemma is surprisingly useful.  For example, it is not hard to use it to show that $m! (n!)^m$ divides $(mn)!$.

Comment: Among many nice answers, I like this one the best.

Comment: Hmm it's also not hard to see that $\frac{(mn)!}{m!(n!)^m}$ is the number of ways of putting $mn$ distinct objects into $m$ groups, since the number of ways to permute the groups is $m!$ and the number of ways of permuting within every group is $(n!)^m$. Any not so trivial usage of that lemma?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Can you please help me how to use the lemma to prove your proposed question. I have also asked it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1574830/prove-that-mn-is-divisible-by-n-cdotmn).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks, I really like your answer.

Answer (score 22):

Here is another proof:

We use Legendre's formula for the exact power of a prime $p$ which divides $n!$ which is given by

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor$$

where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the integer part of $x$.

Coupled with $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \left\lfloor x_i\right\rfloor \le \left\lfloor\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \right\rfloor$$

we get that if $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i = N$ then

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left\lfloor\frac{a_i}{p^k}\right\rfloor \le \left\lfloor\frac{N}{p^k}\right\rfloor $$

And so any prime power which divides $(a_1)! \dots (a_n)!$ divides $N!$ and so $\displaystyle \frac{N!}{(a_1)! \dots (a_n)!}$ is an integer.

Answer (score 19):

These quotients are integers since they solve counting problems.
For instance, how many nine-letter words are there with 2 As, 3 Bs and 4 Cs?

For the full story see the [multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Comment: While true, it's not a good answer - usually one needs to be convinced that the quotients are integers *before* they can understand why the results are the solution to a counting problem...

Comment: @BlueRaja: Not at all! Showing that some ratio is the solution to a counting problem is my favourite way of proving divisibility. You don't need to be convinced that the quotient is an integer here; once you show it's the number of [something], it *has* to be an integer. (You don't usually check divisibility and compare prime factors when you show that the number of ways of choosing k out of n is $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.)

Answer (score 18):

If you believe (:-) in the two-part Newton case, then the rest is easily obtained by induction. For instance (to motivate you to write a full proof):

$$\frac{9!}{2! \cdot 3! \cdot 4!}\ =\ \frac{9!}{5!\cdot 4!}\cdot \frac{5!}{2!\cdot 3!}$$

Comment: In terms of multinomial coefficients: choosing (2, 3, and  4) out of 9 is the same as first choosing 4 from the original 9, then choosing 2 and 3 out of the remaining 5. Etc.

Answer (score 11):

Besides the obvious combinatorial interpretations, one also has the has the following reduction from multinomial coefficient to products of binomial coefficients. Namely for $n = i+j+k+\cdots + m $

$$ \frac{n!}{i!j!k!\cdots m!} = \binom{n}{i} \frac{(n-i)!}{j!k!\cdots m!} = \binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{j} \frac{(n-i-j)!}{k!\cdots m!} = \;\cdots$$

Answer (score 11):

$$\frac{(x+y+z)!}{x!y!z!} = \binom{x + y + z}{x + y} \binom{x + y}{x}.$$

Answer (score 6):

To show that $\frac{(x+y+z)!}{x!y!z!}$ is an integer (when $x$, $y$, and $z$ are non-negative integers) it is enough to show that $\frac{(x+y+z)!}{x!y!z!}$ **counts something**.

Consider all words of length $x+y+z$ made up of $x$ occurrences of the letter A, $y$ occurrences of the letter B, and $z$ occurrences of the letter C. There are $\frac{(x+y+z)!}{x!y!z!}$ such words.

Answer (score 3):

Let's prove using induction, the special case of two numbers, i.e., the statement that if $p, q$ $\in \mathbb{N}$ then $p!q!|(p+q)!$.

(Assume any new variables introduced below to refer to natural numbers.)

First note that since $(p+1)! = (p+1)p!1!$, the statement is true for $q = 1$ and any $p$ (including $p = 1$). In particular, it is true for $p + q = 1 + 1 = 2$. Let us assume that the statement holds for $p, q$ such that $p + q = n$.

Now, for $p, q$ such that $p + q = n + 1$, we can write 
$$(p + q)! = (p + q)(p + q - 1)!$$ 
$$= p [\underbrace{(p - 1) + q}_n]! + q [\underbrace{p + (q - 1)}_n]!$$ 
$$= p \underbrace{k_1 (p-1)!q!}_{\text{using induction assumption}} + q \underbrace{k_2 p!(q-1)!}_{\text{using induction assumption}}$$ 
$$= (k_1 + k_2) p! q!$$. Hence the principle of mathematical induction implies the truth of the statement.

Now it is easy to prove the analogous statement for three numbers, i.e. $p!q!r! | (p + q + r)!$, since (using the statement just proven) $(p + q + r)!$ is divisible by $p! (q+r)!$ and $(q + r)!$ is divisible by $q!r!$.

This can be generalised for any number of parts, by induction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Write
$$\eqalign{(x+y+z)!
  &=[(1)(2)\cdots(x)]\cr
  &\qquad{}\times[(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+y)]\cr
  &\qquad{}\times[(x+y+1)(x+y+2)\cdots(x+y+z)]\cr}$$
and use a well-known fact about a product of $n$ consecutive integers.

Answer (score 1):

The number of powers of $p$ dividing $n!$ is $\sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \rfloor$, and we have $\lfloor \frac{x+y+z}{q} \rfloor \geq \lfloor \frac{x}{q} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{y}{q} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{z}{q} \rfloor$.