# Help me prove that $\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}$ is a natural number by induction.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

When $n$ is a natural number, prove that $\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}$ is a natural number.

If possible, I would like you to prove this by induction.

I tried to prove this by induction, but I can’t because $k+1$ is left in the denominator when I substitute $k+1$ to $n$.

Help me to solve this.

Comment: please prove by induction

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382787/induction-proof-dbinom2nn-dfrac2nnn-is-an-integer?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 7):

Doesn't this suffice?
$$
\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}
=\frac{(2n)!}{n!\,n!}
=\binom{2n}{n}
$$

Comment: Still you have to prove that it is an integer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382787/induction-proof-dbinom2nn-dfrac2nnn-is-an-integer?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @GuyFsone, not if you use that $\binom{m}{n}$ is the number of subsets of size $n$ out of $m$ objects.