# Formal proof $\binom{n}{k}$ is an integer

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

In mathematics one defines:

$\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\k\end{array}\right)=\displaystyle\frac{n!}{k!\cdot (n-k)!}$

This is the number of combinations of $k$ elements from a collection of $n$ elements.

I was wondering if it is possible to prove that the result is an integer in a formal way. It's easy to see that $k!$ in the denominator divides the numerator, but how do you prove that the denominator $k!$ also divides the product of all elements between $n-k+1$ and $n$?

Comment: Basically what you want to know is why
$$
k!\: | \: n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)
$$
right? One approach is looking at prime factors. Show that for any prime, among all $k$ long products of consecutive (natural) numbers, $k!$ is (tied for) the one with least divisibility by $p$.

Comment: Hint: Apply complete mathetical induction to prove
$${n \choose k} = {n-1 \choose k-1} + {n-1 \choose k} $$

Comment: You say that $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of combinations of $k$ elements from a collection of $n$ elements [1]. If $x$ is equal to an integer, is it not a proof that $x$ itself is an integer? A formal way to express [1] is Newton's binomial theorem.

Comment: Excuse my naivety, but for a list of consecutive numbers of length N, won't there alway be a number in the list divisible by each of $1 \dots N$ ?

Comment: @stevemarvell yes, but the same number might be used in two different cases, so you should rule out this case.

Comment: @mau we clearly know that it works, so there must be some more "English" which I could have used to expand the explanation. Clearly you mean something like having a number like 4, which could  have candidate factors 4 and 2. If this is the case, then the length of the list of number must be at least 4, in which case there must be two candidates for 2.

Comment: See this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial/12073#12073).

Comment: @stevemarvell in the sense that it's true that in {28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33} there is a multiple of 5 and a multiple of 6, but they are the same number. So you cannot just make a simple association, but at least you should work with the factors.

Comment: @mau I can see the point, but in this case it doesn't matter. I know that's not a very formal thing to say. In fact, in any list with a prime number in it, there will exist a number for which the denominator is applied at least twice. It strikes me that you example could only have been contrived (for want of a better word) if the list contained a number which had factors of both. The one I've been toying with is ${13,14,15,16,17}$. I can't generate an example where "cancelling" twice or more times with the same number causes a problem. But then that's to be expected.

Comment: @stevemarvell it's clear that eventually the result must be an integer, since there's a combinatorical way to prove it. I only wanted to say that the naive argument has to be fleshed a bit.

Comment: @mau I agree. It's the fleshing that I can't prove. Thanks for the indulgence.

Comment: @stevemarvell when I stumbled into this problem last year, and searched for a non-combinatorial solution, I eventually used the counting argument for numbers of the form $p^m$ (you need also power of primes: for example for $n=13$ you first show that there is one multiple of 8, then that there are a total of three multiples of 4, and last that there are a total of six multiples of 2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\frac{n!}{k!\cdot (n-k)!}
=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}
=\frac{(n-k+k)(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}\\
=\frac{(n-1)\cdots(n-k)}{k!}+
\frac{(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{(k-1)!}
$$
Now use (double) induction.

This is the relation that defines [Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle):
$${n \choose k} = {n-1 \choose k} + {n-1 \choose k-1}.$$