# Let $m=p^t$ where p is a prime. Prove that $a^{\phi(m)+t} \equiv a^t \bmod{m}$ for ${\bf all}$ integers a

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

So, I was thinking that $a^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1 \bmod{m}$, thus when multiplying $a^t$ on both sides, we get that $a^{\phi(m)+t} \equiv a^t \bmod{m}$. What is throwing me off is the all integers a part.

Answer (score 1):

$$a^{\phi(p^t)+t}-a^t=a^t(a^{\phi(p^t)}-1)$$

Now as $p$ is **prime**;  either $p$ divides $a$ or $p\not|a\iff (p,a)=1$

If $p$ divides $a, p^t|a^t$

Else $(p,a)=1$ which can safely use Euler's Totient Theorem

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but is the $a^{\phi(p^t) + t} - a^{\phi(t)}$ supposed to be $a^{\phi(p^t) + t} - a^t$?

Comment: @user2977382, Sorry for the typo

Comment: So If I am understanding this correctly, if $p^t \mid a^t$ then we get $a^{\phi(t)}*a^t - a^t \equiv 0 \bmod{p^t}$ and subsequently $0 \equiv 0 \bmod{p^t}$ which is true?

Comment: @user2977382, Agreed

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you live on this site? I see you everywhere.

Comment: @user2977382, My pleasure. Could I make the idea clear