# Proving $n^{97}\equiv n\text{ mod }4501770$

Tags: abstract-algebra, congruences, computer-algebra-systems

How do we show $$n^{97}\equiv n\text{ mod }4501770$$ for all integer $n$? First of all, I thought I could use [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) or [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), but I'm not sure if they are applicable here.

Comment: You have to work one prime at a time. For example, $n^{96} \equiv 1$ (mod $5$) if $n$ is not divisible by $5,$ so $n^{97}-n$ is always divisible by $5.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $\displaystyle4501770 =2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot13\cdot17\cdot97$

Using Fermat's Little Theorem prime $p$ always divides $(n^p-n)=n(n^{p-1}-1)$

For example, $\displaystyle p=17, n^{97}-n=n(n^{96}-1)=n\{(n^{16})^6-1^6\}$ which is a multiple of $n(n^{16}-1)$ which is divisible by $17$ for all integer $n$

Similarly for the rest of the factors (which are also prime)

Now as $n^{97}-n$ is divisible by $2,3,5,7,13,17,97;$

$n^{97}-n$ will be divisible by their LCM which is their product here(right? why?)

Regarding how $96$ is identified, what is the LCM$(2-1,3-1,5-1,7-1,13-1,17-1,97-1)$

See also : [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html) and calculate $\lambda(4501770)$

Comment: So to summarise: it all comes down to the fact that $m=4501770$ is a squarefree number with the property that for any prime $p$, if $p\mid m$ then $p-1\mid m-1$.

Comment: @David, In fact, it does not has to be. For example $8$ always divides $\displaystyle n^3(n^2-1);9|n^2(n^6-1)$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee The elements in $\left\{2,3,5,7,13,17,97\right\}$
 are pairwise coprime, so their LCM is their product.

Comment: @oxbadfood, Nice to hear that. See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652126/proof-that-a5-b-b5-a-is-divisible-by-30-for-any-integers-a-and-b

Comment: @labbhattacharjee so in your comment you are asserting, correctly, that the *converse* of my comment is not true.

Comment: @David, What do you mean by converse?

Comment: If the conditions in my comment are true then the OP's result is true.  You have correctly stated that if the conditions in my comment are false then the OP's result need not be false.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee One last question: We've got $$4501770\;|\;(n^{97}-n)\Leftrightarrow n^{97}\equiv n\text{ mod }4501770$$ So, there's nothing more to show. But you've asked me to consider $$\text{lcm}\left\{2-1,3-1,5-1,7-1,13-1,17-1,97-1\right\}=96=\lambda (4501770)$$ I can see that there's a useful relation between these things, but how does it help initially (before we've shown the divisibility properties) in this question?

Comment: @oxbadfood, Any problem is best understood by its origin. Here is does not have to be $97$. it can be $$n^{96a+1}-n$$ right?