# How to prove that $42|a^7-a$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Suppose we are given a number $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ prove that $42|a^7-a$.

I'm not too sure how to start any ideas?

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22121/how-can-i-prove-that-n7-n-is-divisible-by-42-for-any-integer-n)

Answer (score 2):

Reduce $a^7-a$ mod 2,3, and 7 (the factors of 42) and show in each case that you get 0, so that 2,3, and 7 are all factors of $a^7-a$

Comment: please explain further I don't understand.

Comment: factor $a^7-a$, and you'll see that $a^3-a$ and $a^2-a$ are factors.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ It follows immediately from a slight generalization of [$\color{#c00}{\rm Fermat's}$ little Theorem:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

- $ $ If $\ p\!-\!1\mid e\!-\!1\,$ then $\, {\rm mod}\ p\!:\ a^e\equiv a.\,$ Indeed, it is true if $\,a\equiv 0,\,$ and if $\,a\not\equiv 0\,$ then $\,e\, =\, 1+k(p\!-\!1)\ $ so $\ a^e\equiv a (\color{#c00}{a^{p-1}})^k\overset{\rm\color{#c00}{ Fermat}}\equiv a \color{#c00}{(1)}^k\equiv a,\ $ so $\ a^e\!-a\equiv a-a\equiv 0.$

In your case we have $\,2\!-\!1,\,3\!-\!1,\,7\!-\!1$ all divide $\,e\!-\!1 = 7\!-\!1,\,$ so $\,a^7-a\,$ is divisible by $\,2,3,7,\,$ therefore it is also divisible by their lcm = product $ = 42.$

**Remark** $\ $ Above we used  [basic congruence rules.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)  The key idea generalizes, see [Korselt's Carmichael Number Criterion.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1151657/242)

Comment: This looks great but it's way beyond my reach congrats though you are very much a genius.

Comment: @James You can safely ignore the Remark. Everything before it is very easy, using only Fermat's little Theorem and congruences. If anything is not clear, please feel welcome to ask questions, and I will be happy to explain further.

Comment: No worries mate. I know that it is just me now. Definitely starting to think I am not cut out for this as it takes me ages to understand things and I can never get answers on my own. Appreciate the effort though :)

Comment: @James Do you know Fermat's little Theorem, and congruence (modular) arothmetic? If so, then you *can* understand this. Please tell me where I lost you and I can elaborate.

Comment: Yes I know FLT but I never understood the proof when I saw it in class. I think I understand this question now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $42$ is the largest integer that divides $a^7-a$ for all $a\in\Bbb Z$.

$a^7-a=a\left(a^6-1\right)=a\left(a^3-1\right)\left(a^3+1\right)$

$=a(a-1)\left(a^2+a+1\right)(a+1)\left(a^2-a+1\right)$

$a-1,a,a+1$ are three consecutive integers, so $2,3\mid a^7-a$.

Also by Fermat's Little theorem $7\mid a^7-a$. Therefore $2\cdot 3\cdot 7=42\mid a^7-a$.

$2^7-2=42\cdot 3$ and $3^7-3=42\cdot 52$. But $\gcd(3,52)=1$,

so it follows that $42$ is the largest integer that divides $a^7-a$ for all $a\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: by far, the best answer given.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fermat's little theorem mod 2, 3 and 7 since these are the prime factors of 42.

Answer (score 0):

First by the Fermat's little theorem we have $$a^7\equiv a \bmod 7$$ so $7|a^7-a$. On the other hand by applying the same theorem it is easy to see that $$2|a^7-a$$ and $$3|a^7-a \quad*$$

**Proof of** $3|a^7-a$.

If a is a multiple of $3$, * is clear. So suppose that $\gcd (a,3)=1$. Then Fermat's theorem implies that $$a^2\equiv a\bmod 3\implies a^6\equiv a^3\equiv a^2\times a\equiv a\times a\equiv a \bmod 3 \implies a^7\equiv a^2 \equiv a\bmod 3$$ 
Could you repeat this for the other case?

Comment: Okay so I get the case when n=7 but what about for the n=3 case I get $a^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ how do I get $3|a^7-a$ from this?

Comment: $a^2$ won’t be $\equiv1\pmod3$ if $3|a$.

Comment: Apply fermat's little theorem with p=3 and that's what you get though?

Comment: See the edit. @JamesK

Comment: @Lubin if 3|a then 3|a^2 so $a^2\equiv 0\bmod 3$

Comment: @Fermat, I was correcting James K’s remark that for the $n=3$ case, $a^2\equiv1$.