# Congruence of square-free numbers

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Let $m$ be a square-free number.  I want to prove that, given some $b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, where $\gcd(b,m)>1$, that

$\qquad b^{\,c\,\phi(m) + 1} \equiv b \pmod m,\ $ for some $c \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

I've verified this with a bunch of different values of $m$ and $b$, but I'm really stuck on how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $b=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\ldots p_k^{a_k}$, where $p_1, p_2, \ldots p_k$ are prime divisors of b. We'll prove there exist $c$ (actually every natural number works), such that:

$$p_1^{a_1(c\phi(m)+1)} \equiv p_1^{a_1} \pmod {m}$$
$$p_2^{a_2(c\phi(m)+1)} \equiv p_2^{a_2} \pmod {m}$$
$$\cdots$$
$$p_k^{a_k(c\phi(m)+1)} \equiv p_k^{a_k} \pmod {m}$$

Get the first relation and divide with $p_1^{a_1}$ since $m$ is square integer, one is the highest power $p_1$ that devides it. Now we get:

$$p_1^{a_1c\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$$

where $n=\frac m{gcd(m,p_1)}$, obviously $(n,p_1) = 1$ since m is squarefree integer. Now use the fact that the Euler Totient Function is multiplicative for relatively prime numbers and that $p_1^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$:

$$p_1^{a_1c\phi(m)} \equiv p_1^{a_1c\phi(n) \phi(p_1)} \equiv (p_1^{\phi(n)})^{a_1c\phi(p_1)} \equiv 1^{a_1c\phi(p_1)}  \equiv 1 \pmod n$$

Simularly we prove for each of the congruence relations.

Now just multiply all the congruence relations and we have:

$$(p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\ldots p_k^{a_k})^{c\phi(m) + 1} \equiv p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\ldots p_k^{a_k} \pmod m$$
$$b^{c\phi(m) + 1} \equiv b \pmod m$$

Hence the proof.

---

You can directly prove this by using a nice lemma that another MSE user has proved: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151620/proving-n17-equiv-n-textmod-510/1151657#1151657). Subsitute $e=c\phi(m) + 1$ in his answer and use that $p-1 = \phi(p)$ and the fact that $m$ is squarefree.

Comment: One quick question, what if n is not an integer?  Let's say that m = 3*5*11 = 165, and b = 121.  n would be 165/121, so how would calculate modulus n.

Comment: @user879559 Then you get $n=\frac {165}{11}$. I guess you know that when dividing in congruence relation if the number we divide with doesn't divide the modulo, the modulo doesn't change. So to become clearer divide twice by $11$, after the first dicision you'll have:

$${11}^{2c\phi(165) + 1} \equiv 11 \pmod {15}$$

After the second one you'll edn up with:

$${11}^{2c\phi(165)} \equiv 1 \pmod {15}$$

Comment: @user879559 You may want to see the new better answer. Also I left you a link to another thing I think may interest you.

Comment: @user879559 Well could you tell me why we need to sho what e should be square free? As I've said set $e=c\phi(m) + 1$. For $m=105$, $\phi(m)=48$. Then for $c=6$, we have $e-1=288$. Then obviously $p-1 \mid e-1$ for each prime divisor of $m$. Hence the proof using the lemma