# Extension to Korselt's Criterion

Tags: number-theory

For a Carmichael number $n$, and $p$ a prime that divides $n$, show that $p-1$ divides $\dfrac{n}{p}-1$.  I'm not sure on where to start for this proof, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean if $p$ is prime and $p|n$?  For instance, since $67*133 = 8911$, you have also have $66|132$

Comment: Yes, sorry let me edit my OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\ n = pk\ $ then $\ n\!-\!1 = (p\!-\!1)k + k\!-\!1\ $ so $\,p\!-\!1\mid n\!-\!1 \iff p\!-\!1\mid k\!-\!1 = \frac{n}p\!-\!1$

**Remark** $\ $ A complete proof of Korselt's Criterion is in [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1151657/242)