# Is the following proof correct for $n(n+1)(n+5) = 3X$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The objective is to prove that $n(n+1)(n+5)$ is a multiple of 3.

I took the following simplistic route $$n(n+1)(n+5) = 3X$$
$$n(n+1)(n+5)\frac{n+2}{n}\frac{n+6}{n+5} = 3X*\frac{n+2}{n}\frac{n+6}{n+5}$$

Now, since $(n+1)(n+2)(n+6) = 3X*Y$, n+1 should be divisible by 3 as long as n is divisible by 3 (Proof by induction).

Obviously i don't feel that is the right answer, it feels like cheating. I can't see how this method is illegal however.

Comment: The quantity you are referring as $Y$, why is that an integer?

Comment: Since this is a proof by induction, i assume that Y is an integer since the assumption is that n is a multiple of 3.

Comment: Are you given that $n$ is a multiple of $3$?

Comment: No. The objective is to prove $n(n+1)(n+5)$ is a multiple of 3 by induction. In it, we're assuming that any natural number n is a multiple of 3 and then applying the induction case to prove that if n is a multiple of 3, so must n+1. So, it is not given that n is a multiple of 3, but it is an assumption for the induction.

Comment: That is an incorrect assumption. How can $n$ and $n+1$ both be multiples of $3$. Unless you meant that you are assuming the statement holds for $n$ case and you are trying to prove for the $n+1$ case.

Comment: I made a mistake in the comment above. We're trying to prove that $n(n+1)(n+5)$ is a multiple of 3 for all natural numbers n.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/971367/use-the-division-algorithm-to-prove-that-3n%C2%B3-2n-for-all-n-%E2%88%88-%E2%84%95

Comment: Well, of course n(n+1)(n+5) is divisible by 3 if n is divisible by three.  That's obvious.  But you have to prove n(n+1)(n+5) is divisible by 3 if n is *not* divisible by three.

Comment: "since the assumption is that n is a multiple of 3" "we're assuming that any natural number n is a multiple of 3".  why on earth do you think that is what you are supposed to be doing?  You *know* that that is not true because 1,2, 4,5,7,8,10 etc.  are all not multiples of 3.  So assuming that any natural number n is a multiple of 3, is a ridiculous and pointless thing to assume  I don't think you understand how a proof by induction is supposed to work.

Comment: Prove by induction: show that if n = 1; n(n+1)(n+5) = 1*2*6 = 12 is divisible by 3.  show that if we somehow knew that if for some m, m(m+1)(m+5) is divisible by 3, then we can prove that (m+1)(m+2)(m+6) is divisible by 3.  Note: we can do that:  m(m+1)(m+5) is div by 3 so (m+3k)(m+1 + 3j)(m+ 5 + 3v) are also divisible by 3 for all k,j,v so (m+6)(m+1)(m + 5 -3) = (m+1)(m+2)(m+6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is not correct
because
$\frac{n+2}{n}\frac{n+6}{n+5}
$
is never an integer.
Just looking at it,
$\frac{n+2}{n}\frac{n+6}{n+5}
=\frac{n^2+8n+12}{n^2+5n}
=\frac{n^2+5n+3n+12}{n^2+5n}
=1+\frac{3n+12}{n^2+5n}
$,
and
$n^2+5n > 3n+12$
when
$n^2+2n>12$
or
$(n+1)^2 > 13$
which is true for $n \ge 3$.

A proof by induction
could go like this:

Base case:
For $n=1$,
$n(n+1)(n+5)
=1\cdot 2 \cdot 6
=12
$
is divisible by 3.

Induction step:
The difference between
the expression for
$n+1$ and $n$ is

$\begin{array}\\
(n+1)(n+2)(n+6)-n(n+1)(n+5)
&=(n^3+9 n^2+20 n+12)-(n^3+6n^2+5n)\\
&=3n^2+15n+12\\
&=3(n^2+5n+4)
\end{array}
$

and this is obviously divisible by 3.

Therefore,
if 
$n(n+1)(n+5)$
is divisible by 3,
so is
$(n+1)(n+2)(n+6)$.

Since
$n(n+1)(n+5)$
is divisible by 3
for $n=1$,
it is divisible by 3
for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $n(n+1)(n+5) = n(n+1)(n+2 + 3)$

$= n(n+1)(n+2)+3n(n+1)$

So just prove the product of 3 consecutive numbers is a multiple of 3.

Now as Anurag mentioned, $n$ can be of the form $3k$ or $3k+1$ or $3k+2$. In all cases, show that $n(n+1)(n+2)$ is divisible by 3.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand. Why is (n+1)(n+2+3) consecutive?

Comment: @AayushAgrawal what Tim means is $n+2$ and $n+2+3$ will have the same remainder when divided by $3$.

Comment: @AayushAgrawal Edited. I am not saying $(n)(n+1)(n+2+3)$ are consecutive. see edit

Comment: But this isn't a proof by induction.  Although it is better in my opinion.  Although the proof by induction has a very nice twist in it:  3 | n(n+1)(n+5) iff 3 | (n+6)(n+1)(n + 2) = (n+1)(n+2)(n+6).

Comment: @fleablood True! I didn't see the post properly! Induction proof( as you marty and anurag too posted) is concise, and doesn't need cases.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

For any integer $n$ there are three possibilities: either $n=3k$ or $n=3k+1$ or $n=3k+2$. For each such possibility show that one of the terms in the product is a multiple of $3$.

---

For proceeding with **induction**: assume it holds for the $n$ case, i.e assume that
$$n(n+1)(n+5)=\color{blue}{n^3+6n^2+5n}=3k$$

Now consider 
\begin{align*}
(n+1)(n+2)(n+6)&=n^3+9n^2+20n+12\\
&=\color{blue}{(n^3+6n^2+5n)}+3n^2+15n+12\\
&=3k+3(n^2+5n+4).
\end{align*}

Thus the left hand side is a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof by induction is !!CUTE!!!

Base: step.  If $n = 1$ then $n(n+1)(n+5) = 1*2*6 = 12$ is divisible by 3.

Induction: Assume that for some $m$ we know that $m(m+1)(m+5)$ is divisible by 3, we want to prove that $(m+1)(m + 1 + 1)(m + 1 + 5)$ is divisible by 3.

Proof:

Let $m(m+1)(m+5) = 3X$.

$(m+1)(m+1+1)(m + 1 + 5) = $(m+1)(m+2)(m+6)$

$=(m+1)(m + 2 + 3)(m+6) - 3[(m+1)(m+6)]$

$= (m+1)(m + 5)m + 6[(m+1)(m+5)] - 3[(m+1)(m+6)]$

$= 3X + 6[(m+1)(m+5)] - 3[(m+1)(m+6)]$

$= 3[X + 2[(m+1)(m+5)] -[(m+1)(m+6)]$ is divisible by 3.

So we are done.

By induction we not the proposition is true for n = 1.  we know if it is true for n it is true for n+1, so inductively it must be true for all natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a proof by induction, start by labeling $f(n)=n(n+1)(n+5)$. Then, you can show that $f(n+1)-f(n)=3(n+1)(n+4)$, which is a multiple of $3$. So:

1. $f(0)=0$ is a multiple of $3$
2. If $f(n)$ is a multiple of $3$, then $f(n+1)=[f(n)]+[f(n+1)-f(n)]$ is a sum of two multiples of $3$, and is hence a multiple of $3$ itself.

Induction does the rest of the work for us from here.

Perhaps interesting to note that $f(n)$ is always a multiple of $6$ - this takes slightly more work, but can be adapted readily by showing that $3(n+1)(n+4)$ is always a multiple of $6$.