# Proof by Induction - Wrong common factor

Tags: proof-writing

I'm trying to use mathematical induction to prove that $n^3+5n$ is divisible by $6$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

I can only seem to show that it is divisible by $3$, and not by $6$. This is what I have done:

Let $f(n) = n^3+5n$.

**Basis Step:** When $n=1$, $f(n)= 6$ and clearly $6$ divides $6$.

**Assumption Step:** Assume that $6$ divides $f(n)$ when $n=k$.

**Inductive Step:** Consider $f(k+1)-f(k)$:
$$f(k+1)-f(k) = [(k+1)^3+5(k+1)]-[k^3+5k]$$
$$=3k^2+3k+6$$
$$=3(k^2+k+2)$$
It follows that $f(k+1) = f(k)+3(k^2+k+2)$. I really wanted a common factor of $6$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$3(k^2+k+2)=6\cdot\frac{k(k+1)}2+6$$

Now $k(k+1)$ being the product of two consecutive integers is even for integer $k$

Non-inductive method:

$$n^3+5n=\underbrace{(n-1)n(n+1)}_{\text{Product of three consecutive integers }}+6n$$

See [The product of n consecutive integers is divisible by n factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial)

Comment: How very cunning! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From your proof...
Note that if k is odd, k^2 + k + 2 is even and hence divisible by 2, and that the same is true if k is even.  Therefore k^2 + k + 2 is divisible by 2 for all k.  this gives you the extra factor of 2 you need to get a factor of 6.

Comment: This "proof" is more of a statement that itself needs proving.