# Can $(k!)!$ be shown to be divisible by $(k!)^{(k-1)!}$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Can $(k!)!$ be shown to be divisible by $(k!)^{(k-1)!}$? What would be the simplest way of showing this?

Answer (score 2):

Lemma: $a!$ divides the product of any $a$ consecutive integers.

Notice that $(k!)!$ is the product of the products of $\frac{k!}{k}=(k-1)!$ blocks of $k$ elements each ( the first block is $1\times 2\times \dots \times k$) , so by the lemma we have that $k!^{(k-1)!}$ divides $(k!)!$

Comment: In fact, the quotient is the multinomial coefficient $$ \frac{(k!)!}{k!^{(k-1)!}} = \binom{k!}{\underbrace{k,k,\cdots,k,k}_{(k-1)!}}. $$

Comment: Oh yeah, my apologies. It should be ok now.

Comment: The product of the $a$ consecutive integers is equal to $a!$, right?

Comment: @M.Berkham not always, for example $3\times 4\times 5\neq 3!$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there a specific name for that lemma? It seems very useful.

Comment: I dont think so, but you can find a prrof here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial. I also answered a similar question a while back here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311466/prove-that-the-expression-frac3n3n-is-integral-for-n-geq-0/1311477#1311477

Comment: Thanks. Is the multinomial coefficient always an integer?

Comment: yes,  at least when the numbers inside the bracket are positive integers and the numbers in the bottom add the same as the number in the top. That is because the multinomial coefficient has a combinatorial interpretation, so it counts things.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the quotient is the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) $$ \frac{(k!)!}{k!^{(k-1)!}} = \binom{k!}{\underbrace{k,k,\cdots,k,k}_{(k-1)!}}. $$

One can go considerably beyond this:

If $(c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n)$ is a nonnegative integer solution to $1c_1+2c_2+\cdots+nc_n$ then

$$ \frac{n!}{1!^{c_1}c_1!~2!^{c_2}c_2!~\cdots~ n!^{c_n}c_n!} $$

counts the conjugacy class of $S_n$ consisting of all permutations with cycle type $1^{c_{\large 1}}2^{c_{\large 2}}\cdots n^{c_{\large n}}$ (which is shorthand for having $c_r$-many $r$-cycles for $r=1,\cdots,n$). This follows from the orbit-stabilizer theorem: $S_n$ acts transitively on conjugacy classes and the stabilizer of a permutation with said cycle type is an internal direct product of internal wreath products.

Specialize to the case $n=k!$ and $c_r=(k-1)!$ when $r=k$ and $c_r=0$ otherwise, giving

$$ \frac{ (k!)!}{ ((k-1)!)!~ k!^{(k-1)!}} $$

is an integer.