# GCD of the elements of a set

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> Let $S$ be the set of numbers of the form
>   $n(n + 1)(n + 2)(n + 3)(n + 4),$
>   where $n$ is any positive integer. The first few terms of $S$ are
>   \begin{align*}
> 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 &= 120, \\
> 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 &= 720, \\
> 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 &= 2520,
> \end{align*}
>   and so on. What is the GCD of the elements of $S$?

Every other number should be even, so $n(n + 1)(n + 2)(n + 3)(n + 4)$ has at least a factor of $2^2=4$ (or $2^3=8$ when $n, n+2$ and $n+4$ are all even). Every third number is divisible by $3$, so $n(n + 1)(n + 2)(n + 3)(n + 4)$ is at least divisible by $3$. Every 5 number is divisible by $5$, so $n(n + 1)(n + 2)(n + 3)(n + 4)$ is divisible by $5$ as well. So I put $3\times 4\times 5 = 60$ as the answer, which is wrong. But I don't think numbers above $5$ are guaranteed to be a factor of $n(n + 1)(n + 2)(n + 3)(n + 4)$...

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial

Comment: As one of the even numbers will be divisible by $4=2^2$, you can increase the power of $2$ that will divide the product, not that that (in general - in this case it's enough) brings you much closer to the result, that can be seen in the question @labbhattacharjee linked above.

Comment: There's a gap in your reasoning: for the entire product $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)$ to be divisible by $8$ it is not necessary for any single one of $n,n+1,n+2,n+3,n+4$ to be divisible by $8$.  The lack of the latter divisibility does not rule out the former.  Also, you already know the GCD is a multiple of $60$.  It also must be a divisor of $120$, the smallest element of $S$.  Not a lot of room in between those values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\ge 1$, the number $$\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}{120}$$ is just the binomial coefficient $\binom{n+4}{5}$ which is always an integer. Hence all the numbers are divisible by $120$.

Because $120$ is the smallest , the $\gcd$ of all the numbers is $120$