# How can I prove

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm in high school so I don't have a lot of proof techniques.I also don't know modular arithmetic so I can't use that either. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: as far as 2, you can calculate the thing for cases $n=2k$ and $n=2k+1.$ In both cases the product is even. Similar for 3, cases are $n = 3w,$ $n=3w+1,$ finally $n=3w+2.$ Just calculation, but you do need to do that much.

Comment: If you know the [sum of squares formula](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56920.html), you'll know that $(2n + 1)(n + 1)n$ is $6$ times the sum of the first $n$ squares.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that either $n$ or $n+1$ is a multiple of 2. Then, there are three cases to see that the number is a multiple of 3 as well:

1. If $n$ is a multiple of 3, no much more to add.
2. If $n$ is a multiple of 3 plus 1, then  $2n+1$ is a multiple of 3, as $2(3k+1)+1 = 6k + 3 = 3 (2k+1)$
3. If $n$ is a multiple of 3 minus 1, then $n+1$ is a multiple of 3.

In any case, $(2n+1)(n+1)n$ is multiple of 6

Comment: Right idea but not quite right. The first sentence is wrong when $n=6$. Settle divisibility by $2$ by looking at $n(n+1)$.

Comment: Corrected. Thx!

Comment: You don't need anything about $n$ mod $3$ to know $n(n+1)$ is even. Do that first. Then just worry about $3$.

Comment: Good point. My solution is effective, it could be more efficient. I changed it following your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

As $n(n+1)$ is even, it is sufficient to show $3$ divides $(2n+1)n(n+1)$

Now $2n(2n+1)(2n+2)$ is divisible by $3,$ being product of three consecutive integers for any integer $n$

$3$ will divide $\dfrac{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}{2\cdot2}$ as $(3,4)=1$

Comment: I really like that trick, using a product of three consecutive numbers. I'll remember that. +1

Comment: @Theo, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial

Comment: I was more referring to the trick of relating $(2n + 1)n(n + 1)$ to $(2n)(2n + 1)(2n + 2)$. I never thought of explaining the divisibility by $3$ in this way.