# Show that $\frac{x(x-1) \dots (x-n+1)}{n!} \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $x \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> **Problem:** Let polynomial $Q_n (x) = \frac{x(x-1) \dots (x-n+1)}{n!} \in R[x]$ for some ring $R$. Show that $\forall t \in \mathbb{Z}, Q_n
> (t) \in \mathbb{Z}$.

**My solution:** For each $t \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $t-1, t-2, \dots, t-n+1 \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $\frac{t(t-1) \dots (t-n+1)}{n!} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $Q_n (t) \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Please check my solution. Thank all!

Comment: How do you know that each of the factors in the numerator is a multiple of one of the numbers from $1$ through $n$?

Comment: You have just stated that all factors in the numerator are integers. But instead, you should show that the numerator is a *multiple of $n!$*. To do this, you can read the answers here: [The product of $n$ consecutive integers is divisible by $n$ factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial).

Comment: You proved nothing. The product of $n$ integers needn't be a multiple of $n!$.

Comment: The combinatorial argument: $Q_n(x)=\binom xn$ is the number of ways of choosing $n$ out of $x\ge n$ objects. For $0\le x<n$, one of the factors of the numerator is $0$. For $x<0$, the argument is similar to the one for $x\ge n$.

Comment: I knew this formulate $\binom{m}{n} = \frac{n(n-1)\dots(n-m+1)}{m!}$. But with this formulate, the prove is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem):
[image: Binomial coefficient generalization]
where $(\cdot )_{k}$ is the [Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol), here standing for a [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_factorial). So,
$$Q_n (x) = \frac{x(x-1) \dots (x-n+1)}{n!} = \frac {(x)_n} {n!} = \frac {\frac {x!} {(x-n)!}} {n!} = \frac {x!} {n! (x-n)!} = \binom x n \in R[x]$$
Now we know that $x$ is an integer so: $\forall t \in \mathbb{Z}, Q_n
(t) \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I know this formula but I cannot prove it