# Prove that the product of n consecutive integers is divisible by n!

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would like to do a proof by induction. I know there's a few duplicate posts about this question but I dont quite understand the notation they have given while showing an induction proof. If someone could post an induction proof without any complex notation for the product of n consecutive integers, I would really appreciate it.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/12121/769495 - this answer, how does $(+1)(+2)...(++1) = (k+1) (m+1)...(m+k) + m^{k+1}$ Can anyone expand this notation to show me whats happening?

Comment: What is the definition of the factorial?

Comment: What is the notation you do not understand?  What posts have already answered this question?

Comment: I know that it is simply a way of choosing a number of integers out of another number of integers so it must theoretically always be an integer but a rigorous proof should work too

Comment: The solutions to this [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial/12073#12073) includes proofs by induction.  the only notation I see is $m^(k)=m\times (m+1)\times \cdots \times (m+k-1)$ which isn't terribly complicated.  If you prefer, you can call it $F(m,k)$ or something like that.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3678062/9003)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial this is the post where i dont understand Nurdin Takenov's answer, especially how (+1)(+2)...(++1) = (k+1) (m+1)...(m+k) + $m^{k+1}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/12121/769495 here is the answer. how does  (+1)(+2)...(++1) = (k+1) (m+1)...(m+k) + $m^{k+1}$

Comment: The line that you don't understand follows from the distributive law.  Just use $(m+k+1)\times A = m\times A + (k+1)\times A$.

Comment: what is the A here? is A = k+1?

Comment: No.  $A=(m+1)\times \cdots \times (m+k)=(m+1)^{(k)}$.

Comment: Maybe it would help to remind you that $m^{(k+1)}$ is NOT $m$ to the $k+1$ power.  Rather, it is defined as the product of the integers from $m$ to $m+k$.

Comment: can you also explain how in the same answer, the second term is divided by (+1)! because of induction by 

Comment: If you divide thru by $k$ it amounts to one of the common inductive proofs of the integrality of binomial coef's using $\binom{a+b}a = \binom{a+b-1}a + \binom{a+b-1}b$. We already have tens if not hundreds of posts on such.

Answer (score 1):

I don't consider this a duplicate question because it's asking for more details, or an alternate proof that's easier.

For an easier proof, induction probably is *not* the way to go.  Rather, let's consider the product of all integers from $m+1$ to $m+n$.  This can be written as
$$
\frac{(m+n)!}{m!}
$$
The binomial coefficient $\dbinom{m+n}{n}$ is itself an integer and has the expansion
$$
\frac{(m+n)!}{m!(m-[m+n])!}
$$
But this is just
$$
\dfrac{\dfrac{(m+n)!}{m!}}{n!}
$$
QED.

Comment: Little remark : $m−[m+n]$ should be $[m+n]-m$. Besides, the question is about a proof by induction.