# Prove that if $a \in \mathbb {Z}$ then for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ it follows that: $k! \mid (a+1) (a+2) \dots (a+k)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I really don't know how to get around this one, tried to rewrite (a+1)(a+2)...(a+k) as $(a+1)^{k} k!$ and that way k! divides k! and even tho it was close I realized $(a+1)^{k} k!$ was not really equal to (a+1)(a+2)...(a+k).
So now I don't have the slightest clue on how to procede

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The product of $n$ consecutive integers is divisible by $n$ factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial). Found by using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24k!%20%5Cmid%20(a%2B1)%20(a%2B2)%20%5Cldots%20(a%2Bk)%24&p=1).

Comment: Write the right-hand side as the binomial coefficient and you should be able to see it