# Proving that $n \choose k$ is an integer

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof that a Combination is an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11601/proof-that-a-combination-is-an-integer)

I can't think how to prove that ${n\choose k} \in\mathbb{Z}$.

I've played with it for a while, using the factorial definition for ${n\choose k}$. Must be something to do with factors but I'm struggling to prove.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11601/proof-that-a-combination-is-an-integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the recurrence identity from Pascal triangle

$$
  \binom{n+1}{k+1} = \binom{n}{k+1} + \binom{n}{k}
$$
and notice that $\binom{0}{0} = 1$, $\binom{n}{0} = \binom{n}{n} = 1$ for $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{ 0 \}$.