# Proof that binomial $\binom{n}{k}$ is an integer for $0>n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I have already looked at this proof here

[Proving that $n \choose k$ is an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65817/proving-that-n-choose-k-is-an-integer?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However I don't understand how I can use the Pascal identity for binommial coefficients if $n$ is a negative number.

I have had the idea to prove a Connection between the negative and the positive Counterpart.

I.e.

Maybe $\binom{n}{k}=-x\binom{-n}{k}$, where $x\in\mathbb{Z}$

I wrote down

$\frac{1}{k!}n(n-1)…(n-k+1)=x\cdot\frac{1}{k!}-n(-n-1)….(-n-k+1)$

What could be the $x$ ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: $\frac{1}{k!}n(n-1)…(n-k+1)=\binom{n}{k}$ is the Definition for General binomial coefficients

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n>0$ we have
\begin{align}
\binom{-n}k
&=\frac{-n(-n-1)\cdots(-n-k+1)}{k!}\\
&=(-1)^k\frac{n(n+1)\cdots(n+k-1)}{k!}\\
&=(-1)^k\frac{(n+k-1)!}{k!(n-1)!}\\
&=(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}
\end{align}
hence it is an integer.

Comment: Can the downvoter please say what is wrong with this answer? $n>1$ for the case $n=0$ one can make a seperate Argument, Therefore. $n-1>0$ and a integer and therefore $n-1+k$ is a natural number. And then with the already known result the Statement is true

Comment: You can't write like this!

Comment: The generale formula of factorial : $\Gamma(n+1) = n!$, for $n$ negative $n! = \pm \infty$

Comment: @LAGRIDA: in my answer, there are no $n!$ with $n<0$.

Comment: but the definition : $n! = n (n-1) \cdots 2$ true iff n > 1

Comment: @LAGRIDA: Actually, $n!$ is defined for $n\geq 0$, with the convention $0!=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method:

Note that

$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k-1}+ \binom{n-1}{k} \space \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} \space \forall k \in \mathbb{N} \\
\Rightarrow \binom{n-1}{k} = \binom{n}{k}- \binom{n-1}{k-1} \space \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} \space \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$

Together with $\binom{n}{0}=1 \space \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$ you can use this to prove by induction that $\binom{n}{k} \space 0>n\in\mathbb{Z}, k\in \mathbb{N}$ is the difference of two integers and so is always an integer.