# Verify proof that ${p \choose r} ≡ 0 \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, congruences

Let $p$ be a prime number. For any $1 ≤ r ≤ p − 1$, prove that
$${p \choose r}
≡ 0 \pmod p$$

---

I'm thinking that it suffices to show $p$ divides ${p \choose r}$. So then:

$$\begin{align}
p\ |\ {p \choose r}
&= p\ |\ {p!\over r!(p - r)!} \\
&= p\ |\ p!{1\over r!(p - r)!} \\
&= p\ |\ p(p - 1)!{1\over r!(p - r)!} \\
&= p\ |\ p{(p - 1)!\over r!(p - r)!}
\end{align}$$

Thus $\displaystyle p\ |\ {p \choose r}$.

But this seems a little too simple to me. Is this really it, or have I missed something? Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is $\{ p\choose r}?$ Please write it between $\$$'s.

Comment: If you knew that $\frac{(p-1)!}{r!(p-r)!}$ was an integer, you'd be fine (though your $=$ signs don't really mean equality; say "if and only if" instead). But you don't know that (unless you prove it).

Answer (score 3):

$$\binom pr=\frac{p(p-1)\cdots(p-r+1)}{r!}$$

Now using [Proof that binomial coefficient is a natural number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125820/proof-that-binomial-coefficient-is-a-natural-number), $\displaystyle(r!)\mid \underbrace{p(p-1)\cdots(p-r+1)}$

But $(r!,p)=1$ for $1\le r\le p-1\implies (r!)\mid \underbrace{(p-1)\cdots(p-r+1)}$