# Prove that $p\mid \binom{p}{k},\ 0< k< p$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, proof-writing

> Prove that:
>   $$p \,\,\left|\, {p \choose k} \right., \quad 0< k \lt p$$
>   if $p$ is prime.

how to prove that with direct proof?

Comment: Hint: think of the explicit definition of $\displaystyle\binom{p}{k}$ as a fraction.  How many times does $p$ divide the numerator?  How many can it divide the denominator?

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: Be careful that $k>0$ since $\binom{p}{0}=1$ and then it is not true that $p|1$.

Comment: Also k < p for the same reason.

Comment: @GautamShenoy You are right, I had not seen that both the inequalities were large in the title.

Comment: Combinatorially, the set ${X\choose k}$ of $k$-subsets of an $n$-element set $X$ ($1<k<n$) can be partitioned into $n$ disjoint equal-sized cells. The cells are $\Gamma_x=\left\{V:x\in V\in{X\choose k}\right\}$ for $x\in X$, which we may intuitively expect to be a partition by considering symmetry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Write out what the binomial coefficient is:
$$
{p\choose k}=\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}.
$$
$p$ divides the numerator since it has a factor of $p$, but $p$ can't divide the denominator because it is the product of integers smaller than $p$ and $p$ is prime.

This means that $p$ does not appear in the prime  factorisation of the denominator, thus you can't simplify the $p$ factor that is on the numerator.

Comment: To complete your argument you could say that $\binom{n}{k}$ is an integer : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11601/proof-that-a-combination-is-an-integer

Comment: @SebastienB I figured when one talks about divisibility problems, they talks about integers :P

Comment: Glad to be of use