# Why does $p$ divide $\binom{p}{k}$ where $p$ is prime?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, divisibility, factoring

On the [Wikipedia page about Binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Divisibility_properties), it states that $p$ divides $\binom{p}{k}$ where $p$ is prime. It offers a proof that I don't understand from the very first line. It says that it is true since $\binom{p}{k}$ is  a natural number and $p$ divides the numerator but not the denominator. I don't get how that shows us anything really.

Please could you explain why the above statement is true?

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear on which part you don't understand.  Do you not understand why $\binom pk$ is a natural number?  Do you not understand why it's represented by a fraction that has $p$ in the numerator but not in the denominator?  Or do you not understand why representing $\binom pk$ as such a fraction yields the conclusion that it must be divisible by $p$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246702/prove-that-p-mid-binompk-0-k-p

Comment: @RobertShore sorry for being vague, I'm unclear about the last option.

Comment: Imagine simplifying $\frac{p(p-1)\cdots(p-k+1)}{k(k-1)\cdots(2)(1)}$ to lowest terms. Since the final result must be an integer, we will cancel out every factor in the denominator with *something* in the numerator. What is left is a multiple of any factor that remains after cancelling everything (and of any divisor of that factor). But because $p$ is prime, the only way we can cancel out that $p$ in the numerator is with something which is a multiple of $p$ in the denominator. Otherwise, we will never use up that $p$. But nothing in the denominator is a multiple of $p$, so that $p$ "survives."

Comment: @MikeEarnest thank you very much. How can I search the site efficiently so I don't ask duplicate questions?

Comment: I disagree with the close votes.  This is a reasonable question seeking clarity on a specific point of the proof that hasn't been previously highlighted.

Comment: I found that by searching the keywords "prime divide binomial coefficient," something similar works best for the search bar on MSE. This only works for search words; to search formulas, use https://approach0.xyz/

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you for the extremely clear explanation.

Comment: For the rep you've earned, you continue to ask some very poor questions.

Comment: @amWhy I'm sorry you feel that way. Poor in what way? I'd like to know how I can improve them.

Comment: Of course you disagree, @RobertShore.  After all you answered a duplicate question, but still want your credit for giving an answer already given.

Comment: @amWhy Really?  Which question answered the question the way I did?  The other answers I've seen more or less duplicated the Wikipedia article that is linked in the original post, so they clearly were not sufficient to clear up the original poster's confusion.  This is exactly the sort of situation where we should be helping, and I submit that the explanation in my answer has not been duplicated elsewhere.  It's certain, based on the comments of A-Level Student, that my answer answered the question in a way the poster found useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $\binom pk = n = p \frac ab$ where $a, b$ are integers and $p$ is not a factor of $b$.  Therefore, $pa=bn$ so $p \mid bn$.  We also know, because $p$ does not divide $b$, that $p$ and $b$ are relatively prime.  Therefore, it must be the case that $p$ divides the other factor of the product, which is $n = \binom pk$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I understand it perfectly now! Don't worry about the close votes (although I appreciate it), the main thing is that you've helped me and I now understand it.

Comment: Acceptances and upvotes of answers you find helpful are always appreciated.  I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I still need to wait a minute to accept it :)