# Binomial coefficient formula: Why the dividend is a multiple of divisor

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Looking at the formula for binomial co-effient,

$$ \binom{n}{r}= \frac {n(n-1)...(n-r+1)}{ 1(2)(3)...(r)} $$

I am wondering why $ n(n-1)...(n-r+1) $ is a multiple of $  1(2)(3)...(r) $ .

I understand from the applications of this formula that only integer values makes sense as in $ n C r $. But, why are these two products be related in such a way, purely thinking of them as product of numbers and from algebra, how can we prove that they will always be related that way.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11601/proof-that-a-combination-is-an-integer

Comment: It is true because ${n \choose r}$ has an independent definition that makes it an integer (namely it is the number of subsets of an $n$-element set of size $r$).