# Prove that $p-1 \mid p^k(p-2)+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove that for prime numbers $p$ and natural numbers $k$, $$p-1 \mid p^k(p-2)+1$$ My initial approach is to check if the numerator is even since the denominator can either be 1 or an even number. Upon inspection, yes. If it is divisible, what could be the form of the divisor... Thanks..

Comment: change divisor by quotient..thanks

Comment: Do you know modular arithmetic?

Comment: I undeastand this problem can be solve by the factor theorem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rearrange:

$$p^k (p - 2) + 1 = p^k (p - 1) + 1 - p^k$$

So it suffices to check that $p - 1 | p^k - 1$. This can be proven by considering

$$p^k - 1 = (p - 1)(1 + p + p^2 + \dots + p^{k - 1})$$

Answer (score 4):

For  integer $k\ge0,$ $$p^k-1\equiv0\pmod{p-1}$$  as [Why $a^n - b^n$ is divisible by $a-b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b)

Alternatively, observe that for integer $k\ge0,$ $$p^k=(p-1+1)^k=\sum_{0\le r\le k}\binom kr(p-1)^r=1+\sum_{1\le r\le k}\binom kr(p-1)^r\equiv1\pmod{p-1}$$ as [Proof that a Combination is an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11601/proof-that-a-combination-is-an-integer)

Answer (score 3):

Think mod $p-1$:

$p\equiv1\pmod{p-1}$ and $p-2\equiv-1\pmod{p-1}$. Therefore,
$$
p^k(p-2)+1\equiv1^k(-1)+1\equiv0\pmod{p-1}
$$
That is, $p-1\mid p^k(p-2)+1$.

Comment: Now that I look at lab's answer, this is pretty close. He had so much extra computation, that I didn't realize it was, in essence, simply a modular argument.

Comment: We can also verify $p=1$ is a zero of the polynomial :)

Comment: @chubakueno: that would require only minor modification of my answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is true in a much more general setting, not just for prime numbers and divisibility of natural numbers. Look at the polynomial $f(X) = X^k (X - 2) + 1$ (over whatever ring $R$ you like). Then $f(1) = 1^k (1 - 2) + 1 = 0$. Therefore $X - 1 \mid f(X)$. Plugging in a specific $x \in R$ then also gives $x - 1 \mid x^k (x - 2) + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

**In what follows, we assume that $p$ is a prime number and that $k$ is a nonnegative integer.**

Still another way to prove that
$$p - 1 \mid {p^k}(p - 2) + 1$$
is by showing that
$$D(p^k) = \frac{{p^k}(p - 2) + 1}{p - 1}$$
where $D(x)$ is the arithmetic function called the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$, defined as
$$D(x) = 2x - \sigma(x)$$
and where $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of divisors of $x$.