# Prove that $6! \mid n(n+1)....(n+5)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial

Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $6! \mid n\cdot(n+1)\cdots(n+5)$ using only criteria of divisibility (without using combinatorial arguments).

Comment: $$\frac{(n+5)(n+4)(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)n}{6!}=\binom{n+5}6$$ See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11601/proof-that-a-combination-is-an-integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $n$, $(n+1)$, $(n+2)$, $(n+3)$, $(n+4)$, $(n+5)$ are all 6 consecutive numbers so one of them is a multiple of 6, and 3 of them are a multiple of 2; and 2 of them are a multiple of 3...

Comment: I was going to give this answer, but I decided not to because it seems to me this is combinatorial.

Comment: @GitGud I think that misunderstands "combinatorial." It is combinatorial if you find a set with $n\cdots(n+5)$ elements that partitions into sets of size $6!$.

Comment: Shouldn't those "at least"s be changed to "exactly"s?

Comment: Technically speaking "at least" is a correct word but as you said "exactly" is much better. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the primes that $6!=2^4\cdot 3^2\cdot 5$ has.

Since $A=n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)$ is a product of six consecutive numbers, there are three even numbers, and there is at least one number divisible by $4$.

There are two numbers divisible by $3$. Also, there exists a number divisible by $5$.

Hence, $A$ is divisible by $2^4\cdot 3^2\cdot 5=6!.$