# What is the simplest way to show that ${(p-1)! \over (k)!(p-k)!}$ is an integer?

Tags: prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, divisibility, proof-explanation

In the proof of $p$ | $\binom{p}{k}$ (p divides $\binom{p}{k}$) where $p$ is prime,

what is the simplest way  to show that $${(p-1)! \over (k)!(p-k)!}$$ is  an integer?

Comment: Use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11601/proof-that-a-combination-is-an-integer

Answer (score 3):

Multiply the numerator by $p$ to get $\binom{p}{k}$, a natural number and note that the denominator can't have $p$ as its factor.