# Logic - Binomial Theorem

Tags: binomial-coefficients, integers

I could use some assistance with understanding this problem.

[image: Proof that I need assistance with]

I understand that there are ${n}\choose{k}$ is a representation of ${n}\choose{k}$ ways to choose k elements from a set of n elements, but I don't understand how this can be represented as a integer. Could anyone point me in the right direction, because I'm not understanding this proof. Thank you!

Comment: There are a few proofs I have seen of this, my favorite being using p-adic analysis. But I think if this is a logic class, the fact that it used to "count" things is probably sufficient.

Comment: Are you allowed to just manipulate factorials?

Comment: If the $\binom{n}{k}$ in the text used is *defined* as a number of subsets it is clearly an integer. But maybe the text defines it using the factorial definition, and then some proof is needed.

Comment: for the binomial theorem, it is obvious that $(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n c_{n,k} a^k b^{n-k}$ where $c_{n,k}$ are integers, what needs a proof is that $c_{n,k} = \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}$

Comment: @Xorque55 Yes I believe so.

Comment: @coffeemath I believe it is a factorial proof, it is not clear in terms of methods.

Comment: @user1952009 how would you prove that? I don't totally understand what you did.

Comment: how would I prove that $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ ? and hence that $(a+b)^3 = (a^2 + 2ab + b^2)(a+b) = a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2 + b^3$ ? and hence that $(a+b)^4 = (a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2 + b^3)(a+b) = \ldots$ ?

Comment: I believe there is an answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11601/proof-that-a-combination-is-an-integer