# Proof that ratio of products is a natural number

Tags: proof-verification

I have found something very interesting in my eyes.

The following expression
$$\frac{\prod\limits_{i=n+1}^{2n-1}i}{\prod\limits^{n-1}_{i=2}i}$$

(I think) always gives a natural number. Now, of course, I am interested in why this is so and I wanted to ask if someone has an approach for a proof...

Thank you :)

(And yes, I know that I should explain my proof so you can verify it, but I have no approach for an proof, so if you tell me which proof-method I should use I would try it on my own of course :) )

Comment: This is an expression, not an equation.

Comment: It is $^{2n-1}C_{n-1}$

Comment: @WiCK3DPOiSON: OK... So why is $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$ an integer then?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner I've made a mistake then I've deleted my hint ;) Thanks.

Comment: Use:

 1. $$\text{P}_1=\prod_{\text{m}=1+\text{n}}^{2\text{n}-1}\text{m}=\frac{\left(2\text{n}-1\right)!}{\text{n}!}$$
 2. $$\text{P}_2=\prod_{\text{m}=2}^{\text{n}-1}\text{m}=\left(\text{n}-1\right)!$$

So:

$$\frac{\text{P}_1}{\text{P}_2}=\frac{\left(\frac{\left(2\text{n}-1\right)!}{\text{n}!}\right)}{\left(\text{n}-1\right)!}=\frac{1}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{\left(2\text{n}-1\right)!}{\left(\text{n}-1\right)!}=\frac{1}{2}\binom{2\text{n}}{\text{n}}$$

Comment: One last question:$$\\$$
Why is this eqivalent:
$$\binom {2n-1}{n} = \frac {1}{2} \cdot \binom {2n}{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

We can see that $$n!(\text {Numerator}) =1\times 2\times \cdots (2n-1) =(2n-1)! $$ Also , $$\text {Denominator} =(n-1)! $$ as $1!=1$. So, $$\frac {\text {Numerator}}{\text {Denominator}} =\frac {(2n-1)!}{n!(n-1)!} $$ With a little knowledge of [binomial coefficients](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), we can see that this **expression** ( **not an equation**) simplifies to $$\binom {2n-1}{n-1} $$ Hope it helps.

---

**Edit**: For your question as to why this fraction is an integer, [see this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11601/proof-that-a-combination-is-an-integer).

Comment: Okay, thanks! One last expression:
In your last equation, did you forget the break, or is it a vector?

Comment: I am sorry but I can't understand which is the last equation.

Comment: experssion, im sorry... :D

This one
(2n-1 | n-1)     (| means new line..)


This is a Vector, isn't it?

Comment: Oh no no, that's how we write the binomial coefficients.

Comment: Oh, okay. I never heard of them, so I guess, that I have to look it up :P

Comment: Yes, @Gykonik That's why I provided you with the wiki link.

Comment: Okay, thanks! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51078/discussion-between-gykonik-and-rohan).

Answer (score 0):

above question reduces into the statement product of any r consecutive integers is divisible by r!.
[The product of n consecutive integers is divisible by n factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial)

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\prod\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n-1}k}{\prod\limits_{k=2}^{n-1}k}
&=\frac{\frac{(2n-1)!}{n!}}{(n-1)!}\\
&=\frac{(2n-1)!}{n!(n-1)!}\\[12pt]
&=\binom{2n-1}{n}
\end{align}
$$
and [Binomial Coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) are integers as computed in [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle).