# Prove by induction the binomial coefficient is always an integer

Tags: induction, binomial-coefficients

Prove that $\binom{n}{r}$ is always an integer for all $n$ and for  $0 ≤ r ≤ n$.

Comment: Possible to refer to this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11601/proof-that-a-combination-is-an-integer

Comment: Since $\binom{n-1}r$ and $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ are integers, $\binom nr$ is an integer if $0<r<n$.