# For $k,m\in\Bbb Z$ show that $m! \mid (k+1)...(k+m)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

how to prove that $m!$ divides product of $m$ consecutive number .

in other hand :

if we have :$k+1,...,k+m$ then $m! | (k+1)...(k+m)$  $(k,m \in \Bbb Z)$

Comment: Did you try induction on $k$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12067/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-without-using-the-prop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Consider the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom{k+m}{m}$.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: The number $\displaystyle \frac{(k+1)\cdots(k+m)}{m!}$ counts something :)