# $n$ and $n^5$ have the same units digit?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Studying GCD, I got a question that begs to show that $n$ and $n^5$ has the same units digit ...
What would be an idea to be able to initiate such a statement?
testing
$0$ and $0^5=0$
$1$ and $1^5=1$
$2$ and $2^5=32$

In my studies, I have not got "mod", please use other means, if possible of course.

I demonstrated in a previous period that
$$2|n^5-n$$because $$n^5-n=(n+1)n(5n^4+5n+5)$$, 
and$$5|n^5-n$$By Fermat's Little Theorem

Only I do not understand what should happen to the units of the two numbers are equal ... What must occur?

Comment: Well, $n\equiv n^5\pmod2$ and $n\equiv n^5\pmod5$.

Comment: Although not studied'' mod''. Using GCD has no like?

Comment: Well, mod is gcd, since $a\equiv b\pmod n$ if and only if $\gcd(n,a-b)=n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without using any modular arithmetic:

$$n^5-n=n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)=n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2-4+5)=n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2-4)+5n(n-1)(n+1)=$$
$$=(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)+5(n-1)n(n+1)$$

$(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)$ is the product of 5 consecutive integers thus divisible by 2 and 5.

$5n(n-1)(n+1)$ is multiple of $5$ and even.

Answer (score 11):

We know if unit digits of two numbers are same, their difference is divisible by 10 and vice versa.

**Method** $1a:$

Using Fermat's Little Theorem $n^5-n\equiv0\pmod 5$

and $n^5-n=n(n^4-1)=n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)$ which is divisible by $n(n-1)$ which is always even

$\implies 2|(n^5-n)$ and we have $5|(n^5-n)$

$\implies n^5-n$ is divisible by lcm $(2,5)=10$

**Method** $1b:$

As $10=2\cdot5,$

using Fermat's Little Theorem, we have  $$n^5-n\equiv0\pmod 5\text{ and } n^2-n\equiv0\pmod 2$$

Now, lcm $(n^5-n,n^2-n)=n(n^4-1,n-1)=n(n^4-1)$ as $(n-1)|(n^4-1)$

$\implies $lcm $(n^5-n,n^2-n)=n^5-n$ which is divisible by $5,2$ hence by lcm$(2,5)=10$

---

**Method** $2:$

Alternatively, 
$$n^5-n=n(n^4-1)=n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=n(n^2-1)(n^2-4+5)$$
$$=n(n^2-1)(n^2-4)+5n(n^2-1)$$
$$=\underbrace{(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)}_{\text{ product of }5\text{ consecutive integers  }}+5\cdot \underbrace{(n-1)n(n+1)}_{\text{ product of }3\text{ consecutive integers  }}$$

Now, we know the product $r$ consecutive integers is [divisible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12067/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-without-using-the-prop) by $r!$ where $r$ is a positive integer

So, $(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)$ is divisible by $5!=120$ and $(n-1)n(n+1)$ is divisible by $3!=6$

$$\implies n^5-n\equiv0\pmod{30}\equiv0\pmod{10}$$

Comment: Damn, too fast!

Comment: Or $n$ and $n^5$ are both even or both odd ...

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee: Is there another way? Without using mod.

Comment: @MarkBennet Then either $n$ is of the form $2k$ or $2k +1$ order. Right?

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, I am adding an alternative solution

Comment: @marcelolpjunior The point is that their difference is obviously even. An even number divisible by $5$ is divisible by $10$ which gives final digit $0$ and means that the final digits of $n^5$ and $n$ must be the same.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, added an alternative method which strongly resembles "N.S."s method, but proves something more

Comment: @labbhattacharjee  Perfect, but it has been shown that certain $2|n^5-n$ and $5|n^5-n$?
But I do not understand the condition that is required for the digits of the numbers $n$ and $n^5$ are equal.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, if unit digits of two numbers are same, can't we say their difference is divisible by $10$ and vice versa?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Incredible, only that answered all my questions ...
You're right, thank you.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, could I make the idea clear

Comment: @labbhattacharjee It would be very good.

Answer (score 4):

The result can be verified using minimal machinery.  first note that the units digit of $n^5$ is *completely determined* by the units digit of $n$.

The units digit of $n^5$ is one of $0,1,2,\dots,9$. We can verify the result for each of the $10$ cases by a direct calculation.

There are $10$ calculations to do, none of them painful.  We do one of them. Let $n$ end in $8$. Then $n^2$ ends in $4$, so $n^4$ ends in $6$. Thus $n^5$ ends in $8$.

Answer (score 2):

You can write $n=10a+b$, with $b$ the units digit.  Then $n^5=(10a)^5+5(10a)^4b+10(10a)^3b^2+10(10a)^2b^3+5(10a)b^4+b^5$.  As all the terms but the last have a factor of $10$, the units digit of $n^5$ is the same as the units digit of $b^5$.  This justifies testing each units digit to see if the units digit of its fifth power is the same as the digit.  Ten tests and you are done-they all succeed.

Comment: Actually 6 tests are enough, since you can write $n=10a \pm b$ where $b$ is a digit $\leq 5$.

Comment: @N.S.:  Good point.