# What are the last two digits of 1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 + ... +99^5?

Tags: exponential-function

What are the last two digits of 1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 + ... +99^5?

My work:

1^5 ends with 1. 
2^5 ends with 2. 
3^5 ends with 3. 
And so on. 
Do I simply add the ending digits to get my answer?

Comment: Okay, but I haven’t learned mod. What now?

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427744/showing-that-1k2k-dots-nk-is-divisible-by-nn1-over-2/427751#427751

Comment: The question asks for the last _two_ digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the sum as
$$S=(1^5+99^5)+(2^5+98^5)+(3^5+97^5)+.....+ (49^5+51^5)+50^n$$ Then
$100=1+99,=2+98= 3+97,...$ is the common factor of all the baraketed terms. Because $(a^5+b^5)=(a+b)M(a,b)$. Next, $50^5$ is also divisible by 100. So the last two digits in $S$ are $00$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$r^{2n+1}+(m-r)^{2n+1}\equiv0\pmod m$  for  integers $r,n,m$

Set $m=100, 2n+1=5$

$r=1,2,3\cdots,49$

So, we are left with $50^5\pmod{100}\equiv?$

Comment: I don’t know mod.

Comment: @Dora, If you know https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem, $$r^{2n+1}+(m-r)^{2n+1}=r^{2n+1}+\text{a multiple of }m-r^{2n+1}$$  right?

Comment: I’m sorry, but I don’t know that either. Is there a way to do it with the last digits as I’ve started to?

Comment: @Dora, Can you prove https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641443/proof-of-anbn-divisible-by-ab-when-n-is-odd ?

Comment: No. I’m sorry I can’t. I need logic, all this Ian too technical for me.

Comment: @Dora, You have derived  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451927/n-and-n5-have-the-same-units-digit/451929#451929 which is applicable for the unit digit only

Answer (score 1):

$1^5+99^5=(1+99)(1-99+99^2-99^3+99^4)=100(\text{positive number})$ what can you see??
Also 
$2^5+98^5=(100)(2^4-2^3(98)+2^2(98)^2-2(98)^3+98^4)$

My solution is a special case of lab's

Answer (score 0):

Using [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula):
$$S_{99}=\frac{4a^3-a^2}{4}=a^2\cdot \frac{4a-1}{4}=\frac{9900^2}{4}\cdot \frac{2\cdot 9900-1}{3}=33\cdot 25\cdot 9900\cdot 19799,$$
where:
$$a=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$
Hence, the answer is $00$.