# $24\mid n(n^{2}-1)(3n+2)$ for all $n$ natural problems in the statement.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

"Prove that for every $ n $ natural, $24\mid n(n^2-1)(3n+2)$"

Resolution:
$$24\mid n(n^2-1)(3n+2)$$if$$3\cdot8\mid n(n^2-1)(3n+2)$$since$$n(n^2-1)(3n+2)=(n-1)n(n+1)(3n+2)\Rightarrow3\mid n(n^{2}-1)(3n+2)$$and$$8\mid n(n^{2}-1)(3n+2)?$$$$$$
***Would not, ever succeeded without the help of everyone that this will post tips, ideas, etc., etc.. Thank you.***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12067/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-without-using-the-prop), the product $n$  consecutive integers is divisible by $n!$ for integer  $n>0$

As $24=4!$and we already have $n(n^2-1)=(n-1)n(n+1)$ the product of $3$ consecutive integers

So, if we can arrange the next or previous term as multiplier, we shall have the product of $4$ consecutive integers, hence divisible by $4!=24$

If we consider the previous term $(n-2),$

$3n+2=3(n-2)+4$

$$\implies n(n^2-1)(3n+2)=n(n^2-1)\{3(n-2)+4\}$$
$$=3\underbrace{(n+1)n(n-1)(n-2)}_{\text{ the product of } 4 \text{ consecutive integers }} +4 \underbrace{(n+1)n(n-1)}_{\text{ the product of } 3\text{ consecutive integers }}$$

If we consider the next term $(n+2),$

$3n+2=3(n+2)-4$

$$\implies n(n^2-1)(3n+2)=n(n^2-1)\{3(n+2)-4\}$$
$$=3\underbrace{(n+2)(n+1)n(n-1)}_{\text{ the product of } 4 \text{ consecutive integers }}-4\underbrace{(n+1)n(n-1)}_{\text{ the product of } 3\text{ consecutive integers }}$$

Comment: Right, got it.
How do these factorizations so "miraculous"?

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, does it look so now?

Comment: Crystal clear... Tank YOu...

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, my pleasure.  Using induction let $f(n)=n(n^2-1)(3n+2)=(3n+2)(n+1)n(n-1)$

and $f(m)$ be divisible by $24$

$\implies f(m+1)=(3m+5)(m+2)(m+1)m$

$\implies f(m+1)-f(m)=(3m+5)(m+2)(m+1)m-(3m+2)(m+1)m(m-1)$ $=m(m+1)\{(3m+5)(m+2)-(3m+2)(m-1)\}=12m(m+1)(m+1)$ which is clearly divisible by $24$ as one of $m,m+1$ must be even

Now, $f(1)=0$ is divisible by $24$ ...

Comment: Heck, pretty cool, here in Brazil induction work differently, but the reasoning is very similar, here it is as if they were steps ... But at the same, I liked ... Thank you.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, my pleasure. Would you please your induction method how it's different?

Comment: +1 Now I see where OP's fascination to products of consecutive integers came from (he asked for it in another question). A perfect match to that. Well done.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I have used  products of consecutive integers here too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459334/prove-that-360-divides-a-2a-1a-a-a1a2

Comment: Good. May be use another trick next time :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$(n-1)n(n+1)$ is product of three consecutive numbers. So they are always divisible by $8$ and $3$ if $n$ is odd. You don't even have to bother about $3n+2$. Now think, what happens to $3n+2$ if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

To prove $8|n(n^2-1)(3n+2)$ you can simply break the problem in three cases:

**Case 1** $n$ odd.

Then $n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$ is the product of two consecutive even numbers. Thus one must be divisible by $4$ and the other by $2$.

**Case 2** $n$ multiple of 4.

Then $4|n$ and $2|3n+2$.

**Case 3** $n$ even but not divisible by 4.

Then $2|n$ and $n-2$ is divisible by $4$. Hence

$$4|3n+2=4n-(n-2) \,.$$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, perhaps more elementary (but lengthier):

$$n(n^2-1)(3n+2)=(n-1)n(n+1)(3n+2)$$

(1) Clearly, exactly one of $\,n-1\,,\,n\,,\,n+1\;$ is divisible by $\,3\,$

(2) If $\,n\,$ is odd, then $\,n-1\,,\,n+1\;$ are even with exactly one of them divisible by $\,4\,\implies (n-1)n(n+1)\,$ is divisible by $\,2\cdot 4=8\;$

(3) If $\,n\,$ is even, then also $\;3n+2\;$ is even, and exactly one of them is divisible by $\,4\,$ , since

$$n=4k+2\implies 3n+2=12k+8=4(3k+2) $$

and again $\;n(3n+2)\;$ is divisible by $\;4\cdot 2=8\;$.

The above cover all the possible cases and in each one the given expression is divisible by $\;3\;$ and by $\;8\;$ , so also by $\,3\cdot 8 =24\;$

Comment: Reasoning interesting, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Newton's interpolation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_series#Newton.27s_series)
gives
$$
n(n^2-1)(3n+2) =  48 \binom{n}{2} + 120 \binom{n}{3} + 72 \binom{n}{4}
$$
which is clearly a multiple of $24$.