# Showing "$30$ divides $n^5-n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$" using induction

Tags: induction

> Prove that $(n^5 - n)$ divides by $30$ for every $ n\in N$, using induction only.

How on earth do I do that? Thing is  $(n^5 - n)$  can't be opened using any known formula...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about "opened", but note that $n^5-n=n(n^4-1)=n(n^2+1)(n^2-1)=n(n^2+1)(n+1)(n-1)$ using twice that $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$, first with $a=n^2, b=1$, then with $a=n, b=1$

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).

Answer (score 11):

If you do want to stick with induction:
The base for $n=0$ (or $n=1$) is clear.
Assume that $n^5-n$ is divisible by $30$. You need to prove that $(n+1)^5-(n+1)$ is also divisible by $30$. Expanding, we get:
$$\begin{align*}
(n+1)^5-(n+1) &= n^5+5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n+1-n-1\\
 &= (n^5-n)+5(n^4+2n^3+2n^2+n)\\
 &= (n^5-n)+5n((n+1)^3-n(n+1))\\
 &=(n^5-n)+5n(n+1)(n^2+n+1)
\end{align*}$$
By IH, $n^5-n$ is divisible by $30$, so it is left to show that $n(n+1)(n^2+n+1)$ is divisible by $6$. It easy to see that it is divisible by $2$. Show that it is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 6):

An alternate technique (not using induction): $n^5-n=n(n^2+1)(n+1)(n-1)$. Clearly $6\mid (n-1)n(n+1)$, and $5\mid n^2+1$ if $n\equiv 2,3\pmod{5}$, otherwise $n\equiv 0,1,4\pmod{5}$, in which case $5\mid n,n-1,n+1$, respectively.

Comment: You can use $n(n^2+1)(n^2-1)$ together with the fact that the squares mod $5$ are $0, \pm 1$ to prove divisibility by $5$, or little Fermat gives it immediately.

Comment: @MarkBennet: You're right :) Both of those are perfectly fine suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Without using induction

$$n^5-n=n(n^4-1)=n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=n(n^2-1)(n^2-4+5)$$
$$=\underbrace{n(n+1)(n-1)(n+2)(n-2)}_{\text{product of }5\text{ consecutive integers }}+5\underbrace{n(n+1)(n-1)}_{\text{product of }3\text{ consecutive integers }}$$

Now from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12067/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-without-using-the-prop), the product of $n$ consecutive integers is divisible by $n!$

Alternatively, using Fermat's Little theorem,

$n^5-n$ is divisible by $5$

$n^3-n$ is divisible by $3$

$n^2-n$ is divisible by $2$

Now, $n^5-n=n(n^4-1)=n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=(n^2+1)(n^3-n)$

and

$n^5-n=n(n^4-1)=n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)=(n^2-n)(n+1)(n^2+1)$

Answer (score 0):

Using induction.
$n=1$: $1^5-1=0$ is divisible by $30$.

$(n+1)^5 - (n+1) = n^5 - 5n^4 + 10n^3 - 10n^2 + 5n - 1 - n + 1$.

Remember that the assumption is that $n^5 - n$ is divisible by $30$. Subtract the assumption from the above and so we need to prove that   $- 5n^4 + 10n^3 - 10n^2 + 5n$ is divisible by $30$.

To show divisibility by $30$ you can show divisibility by all of $5, 3, 2$.

The above is clearly divisible by $5$ as it's $5 \times(-n^4 +2n^3 \ldots$

After dividing by $5$ we can also represent the above as $-n\times(n^3 -2n^2 +2n -1)$.
This is divisible by $2$, because either $n$ is even or if it is odd then $(n^3 -2n^2 +2n -1)$ is even.

Now we need to prove that $-n\times(n^3 -2n^2 +2n -1)$ is divisible by $3$.

$n$ is of the form of either $3N+0$ or $3N+1$ or $3N+2$.
With some labor you can show that in all cases the above is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(m)=m^5-m$

$\displaystyle\implies f(1)=1^5-1=0$

Let $f(m)$ is divisible by $30$ for $m=n$

Now $\displaystyle f(n+1)-f(n)=(n+1)^5-(n+1)-(n^5-n)=5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n$

$\displaystyle=5n(n^3-n)+10(n^3-n)+15n^2+15n$

$\displaystyle=5(n+2)n(n+1)(n-1)+15n(n+1)$

Observe that $n(n+1)(n-1),$ being product of $3$ consecutive integers is divisible by $3$ 
and $n(n+1)$ is divisible by $2$

$\displaystyle\implies n(n+1)(n-1)$ is divisible by lcm$(2,3)=6$

$\displaystyle\implies f(n+1)-f(n)$ is divisible by $30$

But, $f(n)$ is divisible by $30,\implies f(n+1)$ will be divisible by $30$

Comment: @Bak1139, how about this one using induction?

Comment: It's a pretty good suggestion mate

Comment: could you explain a bit more perhaps? also, what do those brackets mean?

Comment: @Bak1139, please have a look into the edited version