# Prove that $(z^3-z)(z+2)$ is divisible by $12$ for all integers $z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, divisibility

I am a student and this question is part of my homework.

May you tell me if my proof is correct?

Thanks for your help!

***Prove that $(z^3-z)(z+2)$ is divisible by $12$ for all integers $z$.***

$(z^3-z)(z+2)=z(z^2-1)(z+2)=z(z-1)(z+1)(z+2)=(z-1)(z)(z+1)(z+2)$

$(z-1)(z)(z+1)(z+2)$ means the product of $4$ consecutive numbers.

Any set of $4$ consecutive numbers has $2$ even numbers, then $(z-1)(z)(z+1)(z+2)$ is divisible by $4$.

Any set of $4$ consecutive number has at least one number that is multiple of $3$, then $(z-1)(z)(z+1)(z+2)$ is divisible by 3.

Therefore $(z-1)(z)(z+1)(z+2)$ is divisible by $12$. Q.E.D.

Comment: You should use the term "integer" instead of number. And you can actually prove something stonger - that it is divisible by $24$. Your proof for $12$ looks correct, though.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for show me my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How can you prove that is divisible by 24? Thanks!

Comment: You can prove it by first proving that the product of three consecutive numbers is divisible by $6$, then prove it by induction on $x$. (That only proves it for $x\geq1$, but it follows easily that it is also true for $x\leq 0$.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I will study your comment. Thanks!

Comment: Of your two even numbers, one must be divisible by $4$.

Comment: @Joffan I did not think about that! Amazing! Thanks!

Comment: @Beginner. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12067/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-without-using-the-prop

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Fantastic! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's correct. Alternatively it is divisible by $\,24\,$ by integrality of binomial coefficients

$$\,(z+2)(z+1)z(z-1)\, =\, 4!\ \dfrac{(z+2)(z+1)z(z-1)}{4!}\, =\, 24{ {z+2\choose 4}}\qquad\qquad$$

Similarly $\,n!\,$ divides the product of $\,n\,$ consecutive naturals.

Comment: @billdubusque Would you mind to explain the last step? I used the binomial and factorial formulas and I got a different result. But, I really like the idea. I did not think about that possibility. Thanks!

Comment: @Beginner $$ {z+2 \choose 4} \,=\, \frac{(z+2)!}{4!\,(z-2)!}\, =\, \frac{(z+2)(z+1)z(z-1)}{4!}$$

Comment: I had a mistake in my computations. Thanks for your help!