# Proving divisibility of $a^3 - a$ by $6$

Tags: divisibility

As part of a larger proof, I need to show why $a^3-a$ is always divisible by $6$. I'm having trouble getting started.

Comment: Note: For the problem to make sense, you need $a$ to be an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$a^3-a=(a-1)a(a+1)$$ which is a product of three consecutive integers.

So, exactly one of them must be divisible by $3$

and at least one of them must be even.

More generally [The product of n consecutive integers is divisible by n! (without using the properties of binomial coefficients)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12067/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-without-using-the-prop)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following options:

- $a\equiv0\pmod6 \implies a^3-a\equiv  0-0\equiv6\cdot 0\equiv0\pmod6$
- $a\equiv1\pmod6 \implies a^3-a\equiv  1-1\equiv6\cdot 0\equiv0\pmod6$
- $a\equiv2\pmod6 \implies a^3-a\equiv  8-2\equiv6\cdot 1\equiv0\pmod6$
- $a\equiv3\pmod6 \implies a^3-a\equiv 27-3\equiv6\cdot 4\equiv0\pmod6$
- $a\equiv4\pmod6 \implies a^3-a\equiv 64-4\equiv6\cdot10\equiv0\pmod6$
- $a\equiv5\pmod6 \implies a^3-a\equiv125-5\equiv6\cdot20\equiv0\pmod6$

Answer (score 0):

by Euler's theorem $ a^{\phi (n)} = a (mod n) $ with $\phi(n)$ the number of integers lower than n and prime with n
if n = 6 there are three integers less than 6 and first ones with 6: 1,3,5
let $a^3 = a (mod 6) $