# Question regarding divisibility.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The expression $a^3+11a-6$ is always divisible by 6.

I came across it while programming and ran it in a function in a calculator.

Upon trying to solve it by myself, I found $a^3+11a-6$ is always even, as when $a^3$ is odd so is $11a$ and when $a^3$ is even so is $11a$, and odd+odd=even and even+even=even.

Now, I tried to find if the number is divisible by $3$, but I couldn't. Can anyone help me out? Why should this expression always be divisible by $6$, we know it is but why?

And is there a way to find if an expression is divisible by a certain number. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with [tag:division-algebras]. Please check the meaning of an unfamiliar tag before using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

$a^3+11a-6=a^3-a+12a-6=a(a+1)(a-1)+6(2a-1)$

What can we say about the product of 3 consecutive numbers?

Comment: At least one of them is divisible by 3 and 1 is even. Thanks a lot

Comment: @SamipGyawali And this is exactly the argument in the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1202868/proving-divisibility-of-a3-a-by-6).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $a^3-a$ is always divisible by $6$, so that also
$$
a^3-a+(12a-6)=a^3+11a-6
$$
is always divisible by $6$.

Reference:

[Proving divisibility of $a^3 - a$ by $6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1202868/proving-divisibility-of-a3-a-by-6)