# Show that the difference between any integer and its cube is always divisible by 6

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that the difference between any integer and its cube is always divisible by 6

Comment: Hint: Factor $x^3 -x$.

Comment: Brute force it over Z_6 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}
\text{Diff}&=x^3-x \\
&=x(x^2-1) \\
&=x(x+1)(x-1) \qquad \text{via }(a^2-b^2)=(a+b)(a-b)
\end{aligned}$$

> **$=(x-1)\cdot x\cdot (x+1)$**

So that always turns out to be product of **three consecutive integers**...which will always have one even number as **2*m** and one number divisible by 3 as **3*n**. Hence the product will always have **minimal factors as 2 and 3**...So, it is divisible by 6.
That's it!!!

Answer (score 3):

$$
x^3-x=(x-1)\cdot x\cdot (x+1).
$$
Between three consecutive numbers, at least one is even, and at least one is multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x-x^3=x(1-x^2)=x(1-x)(1+x)=-(x-1)x(x+1)$$
since $x-1,x,x+1$ are three consecutive numbers and their product is divisible by 6.

Answer (score 1):

$$n^3-n=(n+1) n (n-1)= 6\binom{n+1}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

For the six first $n$, we get $n^3-n=0,0,6,24,60,120$.

Then $(n+6k)^3-(n+6k)=n^3-n+6m$.

Answer (score 0):

If you factorize $n^3 − n$ you will get $(n-1)\cdot n\cdot (n+1)$ and you should know that product of $m$ consecutive integers is divisible by $m!$. (See here [The product of n consecutive integers is divisible by n! (without using the properties of binomial coefficients)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12067/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-without-using-the-prop))

Since $(n-1)\cdot n\cdot (n+1)$ is product of $3$ consecutive integers thus it will be divisible by $3!=6$.