# Use mathematical induction to prove an assertion

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The assertion: $n^3 + 5n$ is divisible by $6$

I have completed the basis step $(n=1)$ and the first part of the induction step $(n=k)$, but I am stuck on the second part $(n=k+1)$.

This is what I have so far:

For $n=k$: $k^3 + 5k = 6t$

For $n= k+1$:

$(k+1)^3 + 5(k+1)$

$= k^3 + 3k^2 + 8k + 6$

$= (k^3 + 5k) + 3k + 3k^2 + 6$

$= 3k^2 + 3k + 6t + 6$
$= ???$

I cannot pull out a $6$ because that would leave halves that cannot be counted as integers. How should I proceed?

Comment: **Hint** $\,\ 6\mid 3k(k+1)\ = 3k^2+3k\,$ since one of $\,k\,$ or $\,k+1\,$ is even

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673037/prove-that-6-divides-n311n

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000484/show-that-the-difference-between-any-integer-and-its-cube-is-always-divisible-by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can complete your work this way:
$$
(k+1)^3 + 5(k+1)=(k^3 + 5k) + 3k + 3k^2 + 6=6t+3k+3k^2+6=6 \left(t+1+\frac{k(k+1)}{2} \right)
$$
and note that $k$ or $k+1$ is even.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Continuing with the work I had completed helped me understand what I was missing.

Answer (score 6):

write $$n^3+5n$$ in the form $$(n-1)n(n+1)+6n$$ and this is the proof.

Comment: Can't beat that...+1

Comment: The question instructs to "use mathematical induction" but your answer does not use induction at all.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Note, $3k+3k^2=3k(k+1)$. As you want to show divisibility by $6$ and $3$ is a factor you only need to show that it is divisible with $2$. What is $k(k+1)$ if $k$ is even? What happens if $k$ is odd?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively. Putting $n=k+1$ into your given expression $n^3+5n$ gives $(k+1)^3+5(k+1)$ (Induction) and that expands to $k^3+3k^2+2k+6k+6$ which can be rewritten as $k(k+1)(k+2)+6(k+1)$. Both terms are divisible by $6$ (why?) and from here I essentially concur with Sonnhard

Answer (score 2):

### Proof by induction

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$1^3+5\cdot1=6$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$n^3+5n=6k$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$(n+1)^3+5(n+1)=$

$n^3+3n^2+3n+1+5n+5=$

$\color\red{n^3+5n}+3n^2+3n+1+5=$

$\color\red{6k}+3n^2+3n+1+5=$

$6k+3n^2+3n+6=$

$6k+6+3n^2+3n=$

$6(k+1)+3\cdot\color\green{n(n+1)}=$

$6(k+1)+3\cdot\color\green{2m}=$

$6(k+1)+6m=$

$6(k+1+m)$

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

---

### Proof by modular arithmetic

**Consider the following cases:**

- $n\equiv0\pmod6 \implies n^3+5n\equiv0^3+5\cdot0\equiv6\cdot 0\equiv0\pmod6$
- $n\equiv1\pmod6 \implies n^3+5n\equiv1^3+5\cdot1\equiv6\cdot 1\equiv0\pmod6$
- $n\equiv2\pmod6 \implies n^3+5n\equiv2^3+5\cdot2\equiv6\cdot 3\equiv0\pmod6$
- $n\equiv3\pmod6 \implies n^3+5n\equiv3^3+5\cdot3\equiv6\cdot 7\equiv0\pmod6$
- $n\equiv4\pmod6 \implies n^3+5n\equiv4^3+5\cdot4\equiv6\cdot14\equiv0\pmod6$
- $n\equiv5\pmod6 \implies n^3+5n\equiv5^3+5\cdot5\equiv6\cdot25\equiv0\pmod6$

Please note that this method is handy only for a relatively small divisor.