# Prove by mathematical induction that $n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+r-1)$ is divisible by $r!$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove by mathematical induction that $n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+r-1)$ is divisible by $r!$.
I tried by proving it true for $r=1$ and then assuming it true for $r=k$ and proving it true for $r=k+1$
But I could not prove that.
Do I need to do the same thing for n?

Comment: @Arthur my mistake, thought it was $n(n-1)\dots (n-r+1)$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12067/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-without-using-the-prop

Answer (score 3):

To save a lot of typing, let me define
$$f(n,r)=n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+r-1).$$
You can verify the identity
$$f(n,r+1)=(r+1)f(n,r)+f(n-1,r+1)$$
which you can then use to prove the statement
$$f(n,r)\text{ is divisible by }r!$$
by induction on the quantity $n+r.$

**Alternatively,** if you're allowed to recast the problem in terms of binomial coefficients, you can prove that
$$\frac{f(n,r)}{r!}=\binom{n+r-1}r$$
is an integer by using [Pascal's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule)
$$\binom x{r+1}=\binom{x-1}r+\binom{x-1}{r+1}$$
to prove by induction on $m$ that $\binom mr$ is an integer for all integers $m,r\ge0.$ (Of course this is just the same proof in different notation.)