# calculating n choose k mod one million

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I am working on a programming problem where I need to calculate 'n choose k'. I am using the relation formula
$$
{n\choose k} = {n\choose k-1} \frac{n-k+1}{k}
$$
so I don't have to calculate huge factorials. Is there any way to use this formula and just keep track of the last 6 digits. Could you compute the next k, with only knowing the some of the last digits.
I understand this is a lot to ask, so all I ask is a point in the right direction.
Maths is by far not my strongest subject.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of the scale of $n$ or $k$?

Comment: 0 <= n, k <= 100.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might also want to use $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$ to reduce the case where $k>n/2$.

Using $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{k-1} \frac{n-k+1}{k}$ mod one million has a problem when $(k,10)\not=1$. Such $k$ are zero divisors mod one million, so you cannot divide by $k$ mod one million and get a meaningful result.

However, you can count the number of factors of $p$ that are in $\binom{n}{k}$ for prime $p$. Let $s_p(n)$ be the sum of the base $p$ digits of $n$.  Then, the number of factors of $p$ in $\binom{n}{k}$ is $(s_p(k)+s_p(n-k)-s_p(n))/(p-1)$.  Thus, instead of multiplying by $n-k+1$ and dividing by $k$, multiply by $n-k+1$ with all factors of $2$ and $5$ removed and divide by $k$ with all factors of $2$ and $5$ removed.  At the end, multiply by the number of factors of $2$ and $5$ computed above.

For example, let's compute $\binom{97}{89}=\binom{97}{8}$.

Here are $97$, $8$, and $89$ in base $2$ and $5$ followed by their sum of digits:
$$
97=1100001_2(3)=342_5(9)
$$
$$
8=1000_2(1)=13_5(4)
$$
$$
89=1011001_2(4)=324_5(9)
$$
Therefore, the number of factors of $2$ in $\binom{97}{89}$ is $(1+4-3)/(2-1)=2$, and the number of factors of $5$ is $(4+9-9)/(5-1)=1$. Therefore, mod one million,

$$
\begin{align}
\binom{97}{8}
&=\frac{97}{1}\frac{96/32}{2/2}\frac{95/5}{3}\frac{94/2}{4/4}\frac{93}{5/5}\frac{92/4}{6/2}\frac{91}{7}\frac{90/10}{8/8}\times2^2\times5^1\\
&=\frac{97}{1}\frac{3}{1}\frac{19}{3}\frac{47}{1}\frac{93}{1}\frac{23}{3}\frac{91}{7}\frac{9}{1}\times4\times5\\
&=010441\times20\\
&=208820
\end{align}
$$
Everything is good above since we can divide by $3$ and $7$ mod one million.

**Caveat:**
Remember that [modular division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) is quite different than standard [division of integers, rationals, and reals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29#Division_of_integers). It requires solving a Diophantine equation which usually involves the Euclidean algorithm. For example, $1/7=3\pmod{10}$ because $3\times7=1\pmod{10}$.

Comment: I see after finally posting that most of what I say is covered in the links supplied by Sasha. I hope the example gives it some added value.

Comment: this is good stuff thanks. It's well explained and I've surprised myself in being able to understand it. +1.

Comment: @ricola86: as long as you remember that division $\pmod{m}$ is quite different than normal division. It requires solving a diophantine equation and usually involves the Euclidean algorithm. E.g. $1/7=3\pmod{10}$.

Comment: +1,Nice explanation,you may also like to add the final comment in the actual answer as well.

Comment: @FoolForMath: Good idea. I have added a caveat to my answer.

Comment: robjohn - how do you derive this $(s_p(k)+s_p(n-k)-s_p(n))/(p-1)$, what is that called?

Answer (score 4):

You may find the following [page](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastBinomialFunction.html) of interest.

Much of the math behind it is also discussed in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51469/prime-dividing-the-binomial-coefficients) at math.SE

Comment: Nice link thanks, It seems I can't upvote with a low reputation :(.

Comment: @ricola86: I upvoted for you.  Oops, now I can't upvote for myself! :-)

Answer (score 3):

In terms of factorials, probably not.

Use the recurrence ${n \choose k} = {n \choose k-1} + {n-1 \choose k-1}$ and just work mod $10^6$.

Alternatively you can work mod $2^6$ and mod $5^6$ and combine the two results using the Chinese Remainder Theorem. There seem to be [interesting patterns in the binomial coefficients mod prime powers](http://math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/jcorn5.html) but I don't know if there are actually formulas. This is probably more trouble than it's worth, though.

Answer (score 2):

I remember solving [SPOJ MARBLES](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/MARBLES/) which is actually finding $\binom{n}{k}$,constraints there are also similar to this problem in hand.

Last January this same problem (with much more difficult constraints) features in [Codechef's January cookfoff](http://www.codechef.com/COOK06).You may like to check the [editorial](http://www.codechef.com/wiki/january-cookoff-contest-problem-editorials) which explains the algorithm along with the implementation.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks alot. Funnily enough, it's a codechef problem I'm working on.

Comment: @ricola86:Aha,glad to help!:-)I didn't practise in codechef anymore,but I guess you are not asking help for any current problem-set?! ;-)

Comment: errmm no, I wouldnt dream of it.

Comment: @ricola86:Alright! :)