# Proving $(\alpha + \beta)^{p^n} = \alpha^{p^n} + \beta^{p^n}$ in a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

> Prove that if $F$ is a field with $p^n$ elements and $\alpha,\beta \in F$, then
>   $$(\alpha + \beta)^{p^n} = \alpha^{p^n} + \beta^{p^n}$$

From Newton identity, we have that
$$(a + b)^n = \sum_{i = 0}^n \binom ni a^i b^{n - i}$$
However, I'm already stuck because in a finite field we cannot necessarily compute the binomial, since we may divide by zero. How do I get around this?

Furthermore, since $F$ has characteristic $p$, isn't it $p^n = 0$? How does it make sense in the first place? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Use induction on $n$. The case $n=1$ follows from Newton Binomial formula, and the induction is easy : $(x+y)^{p^{n+1}} = ((x+y)^{p^n})^p$ ...

Comment: $p^n = 0$ additively or when you multiply it by an element of $F$ (which is really repeated addition), but here $p^n$ appears in an exponent.

Comment: It may be amusing to consider the case of $n = p-1$ and compute $(a+b)^p = (a+b)^{p-1} (a+b)$.

Comment: @lhf I still don't understand. By definition of characteristic, $\underbrace{1 + \cdots + 1}_{p\text{ times}} = 0$. So $p = p\cdot 1 = 0$. But then $p^n = 0$ and we are exponentiating by zero. Does that make sense?

Comment: @lhf Oh no, exponentiation is defined by $a^n$ with $n \in \mathbb Z$, so I have to consider $p^n \in \mathbb Z$. Ok, nevermind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First consider the case $n=1$.  We take the $p$th power as follows:  $(a+b)^p = a^p + {p \choose 1} a^{p-1} b + \cdots + b^p$.  Observe that except for the first and last term in this sum, the coefficient of each term is a multiple of $p$.  Since the field has characteristic $p$, these are zero.  Hence, $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$.  Now take the $p$th power again, and repeat this process $n$ times.

Answer (score 5):

Let $F$ be a finite field with $m$ elements.

By Lagrange's theorem of group theory applied to $F^\times$, we have $z^{m-1}=1$ for all $z \in F$, $z\ne0$.

Therefore, we have $z^m=z$ for all $z \in F$. In particular, $(\alpha + \beta)^{m} = \alpha + \beta = \alpha^{m} + \beta^{m}$.

Answer (score 4):

### It's fine to leave it as an integer

Every ring admits scalar multiplication by integers; you do not need to consider $\binom{n}{i}$ as an element of the finite field.

### It's fine to map it into the finite field

We can always uniquely interpret an integer as an element of any ring by applying the unique map $\mathbb{Z} \to R$. If you want to interpret $\binom{n}{i}$ as an element of the ring, that is how you should do so.

### Either way, study the coefficient first as an integer

As seen [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/51475/14972), there is an explicit formula for how many times $p$ divides $\binom{p^a}{b}$ in the integers:

$$ v_p\left( \binom{p^a}{b} \right) = a - v_p(b) $$

which we can use to show that all of the coefficients except the first and last are divisible by $p$ over the integers.

Then we either argue that we are multiplying by an integer multiple of $p$, or we are multiplying by a finite field element that is $0$.