# Let $p$ be a prime number. Prove that $p^{k}\choose n$ is divisible by $p$ for any $n$ where $1\le{n}\le{p^{k}}-1$ and $k$ is a positive integer.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Any and all help/hints/proofs would be appreciated, I really don't even know where to start.

Comment: Fix title!  It is not clear.

Comment: @herbsteinberg done

Comment: This follows more or less immediately from [Lucas Correspondence](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LucasCorrespondenceTheorem.html). For an on-site proof of that see e.g. [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LucasCorrespondenceTheorem.html). Likely somebody else has written it more lucidly.

Comment: [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem) on the $p$-adic value of binomial coefficients also implies your claim.

Comment: Lest I forget. It looks like you may benefit from studying [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). "I don't know where to start" -questions attract negative attention.

Comment: The $28$ January $2019$ answer by **bof** to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087700/how-to-prove-binomial-coefficient-2n-choose-k-is-even-number) provides another answer to yours.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you so much

Comment: @itseasybutton: You’re very welcome.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you for your valuable information