# Show that for $m\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $k\in \lbrace 1,2,\cdots , p^{m-1} \rbrace$ then $p\mid {p^m \choose k}$

Tags: combinatorics, induction

Show that  for $m\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $k\in \lbrace 1,2,\cdots , p^{m-1} \rbrace$ then $p\mid{p^m \choose k}$ where $p$ is a prime number.

I try induction over $m$, the case $m=1$ implies $p\mid{p\choose 1}$ which is true. Now I suppose that the proposition is true for $m=l-1$  it is I can use $p\mid{p^{l-1} \choose k}$ and I must show that $p\mid{p^l \choose k}$.

Unfortunelly I expand both binomial expressions and I´don´t know how apply a trick to use my induction hypothesis,  also I try use a property of binomial coefficient to reduce the power of $p$, but I´cant find a useful property.

I think that make induction don´t is good idea, but I don´t know other approach of this fact.
Any hint was useful Thanks in advice.

Comment: Cf. [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem).

Comment: I´m gonna try use the theorem

Comment: yes it answer my question

Comment: Note that all the linked answers are proving the stronger statement for all $k \in \{1, 2, \ldots, p^m-1\}$.  You might think this makes it harder, but on the contrary, this is why Daniel Schepler's inductive proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087700/how-to-prove-binomial-coefficient-2n-choose-k-is-even-number) works so easily.  The statement becomes stronger, but it also strengthens the inductive hypothesis, making the inductive step _much_ easier.