# Proving that $\frac{(n+m)!}{m!(n-m)!}$ is an integer for $0 \leq m < n$.

Tags: number-theory

Experiments using a computer seem to indicate that this is true but I am not sure how to prove it. Any ideas?

Comment: It's $\binom{n+m}{m} \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$.

Answer (score 2):

Even more is true:

$$ \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} = {n \choose m}$$
is an integer, because of the combinatorial interpretation of binomial coefficients. Your number is:
$$ \frac{(n+m)!}{m!(n-m)!} = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} \cdot (n+1) \dots (n+m),$$
hence also an integer.

---

By the way,  $\frac{1}{m!} \frac{(n+m)!}{m!(n-m)!} =  {n \choose m}  {n+m \choose m}$, so your number also happens to be a multiple of $m!$.

---

If one does not like to use combinatorics to prove that $ {n \choose m} := \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} $ is an integer, one can:

1. Use induction on $n+m$ and exploit the relation $  {n \choose m} =  {n-1\choose m} +  {n-1 \choose m-1}$ (which is proved by elementary arithmetic). [thanks  Cameron Buie]. Hence, if ${n \choose m} $ are integers for all $n,m \geq 0$ with $n+m < S$, then for $n,m \geq 0$ with$n+m =S$ we have either: a) $n = 0$ and ${n\choose m } = 0 $ or b) $m = 0$ and ${n\choose m } = 1 $ or c) $n,m > 0$ and by induction $  {n \choose m} =  {n-1\choose m} +  {n-1 \choose m-1}$ is a sum of two integers.
2. Use 'pure' number theory and exploit the fact that $n!$ is divisible by a prime $p$ exactly in the power $\lfloor n/p \rfloor + \lfloor n/p^2 \rfloor + \dots$. Hence, it is enough to show that $$\sum_{k} \lfloor n/p^k \rfloor \geq \sum_{k} \lfloor m/p^k \rfloor + \sum_{k} \lfloor (n-m)/p^k \rfloor,$$
   which is straightforward. In fact, this method can immediately be applied to the original problem; it suffices to show 
   $$\sum_{k} \lfloor (n+m)/p^k \rfloor \geq \sum_{k} \lfloor m/p^k \rfloor + \sum_{k} \lfloor (n-m)/p^k \rfloor,$$
   which is easier.
3. Use Google or search feature of MSE:
   [How come $\frac{n!}{n_1!\cdot n_2!\cdot...\cdot n_k!}$ is always an integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269179/how-come-fracnn-1-cdot-n-2-cdot-cdot-n-k-is-always-an-integer?lq=1) ,
   [Division of Factorials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158/division-of-factorials)

Comment: This is sufficient for me but it seems like there ought to be a proof that relies only on the abstract definitions and not only the combinatorial interpretation. It is clear that this problem reduces to showing that the binomial coefficients are integers. I attempted this by induction on $m$ but I cannot get the induction step to work out.

Comment: Nice solution Feanor..............

Comment: @kyp4: If you want to prove by induction that the binomial coefficients are integers, you may find the following fact useful: $$\binom{n+1}k=\binom nk+\binom n{k-1}$$