# Cool property of the number $24$

Tags: alternative-proof

Recently I've had my 24th birthday, and a friend commented that it was a very boring number, going from 23 which is prime, 25 which is the first number that can be written as the sum of 2 different pairs of squared integers $3^2+4^2 =0^2+5^2 =25$, 24 seems like a very boring number

however, it seems to have a very special property

Theorem: product of 4 positive consecutive numbers is divisible by 24.

I managed to prove this via long and dry induction, not very interesting. I wonder if anyone can propose a different more elegant and witty proof, rather than dry algebra like me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In$\;4\;$ consecutive integers $\;(n-1)\,,\,n\,,\,(n+1)\,,\,(n+2)\;$ there are exactly two even and two odd ones.

Of the even ones, exactly one is divisible by $\; 4\;$ so the whole product is divisible by $\;8\;$ , and since *at least* one of the four numbers is a multiple of three the whole thing is divisible by $\;2^3\cdot 3=24\;$ .

Comment: ...Now I feel stupid for actually writing an inductive proof.

Answer (score 11):

We have
$$n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)=\frac{n!}{(n-4)!}=4!\times\frac{n!}{4!(n-4)!}=24\times\binom{n}{4},$$
where the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom{n}{4}$ is known to be an integer.

For more, see these previous questions: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12067/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-without-using-the-prop), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387070/prove-that-a1a2-ab-is-divisible-by-b)

Answer (score 0):

24 is a very special integer number in many regards. John Baez has a nice pdf file about it: [ http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/numbers/24.pdf ], and there is a very good Youtube video you can watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzjbRhYjELo