# How does the mathematical form of nCr ensure that the result is a whole number

Tags: combinations

The mathematical form for nCr is
(n!)/(r!(n-r)!)

How does this form ensure that nCr is indeed a whole number. Is there a mathematical proof?

Comment: Have a look at Gone's answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158/division-of-factorials/2192#2192

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing is that it is the combinatorial argument that $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ *counts* something (i.e., the number of ways to choose $r$ items from $n$ unordered items) that proves (in the most rigorous sense) that it is a natural number. What are proof is needed?

Comment: The argument that a combinatorial argument should be a natural number as it is basically counting something, is perfectly valid. But, I was looking for a more rigorous mathematical proof that the given expression always gives a natural number, not just a logical argument.

Comment: do you consider a logical argument to be lacking in mathematical rigor???