# Show that $P_k(X) = \frac{1}{k!} X (X - 1) ... (X - k + 1)$ is an integer-valued polynomial.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, factoring, integer-valued-polynomials

> For $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let $P_k(X) = \frac{1}{k!} X (X - 1)(X - 2) ... (X - k + 1)$.
>
> Show that these are *integer-valued polynomials*, i.e. $P_k(X) \in \left\{f \in \mathbb{Q}[X] \mid f(\mathbb{Z}) \subset \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

I'm struggling to write down a solid proof.

By induction on $k$, we get $P_{k+1}(X) = P_k(X) \frac{X - k}{k + 1}$, which doesn't really seem to facilitate the problem.

As for a straight-forward proof, I can't generalize the idea behind my thoughts why this should work out.

Comment: See: [Proof that a Combination is an integer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11601/proof-that-a-combination-is-an-integer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of $P_{k}(X)$ for $X = n \ge 0$ is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)
$$
\binom{n}{k}
=
\frac{n!}{k! (n - k)!}
=
\frac{n (n-1) \cdots (n-k+1)}{k (k-1) \cdots 1},
$$
which is an integer, as it counts the ways of choosing $k$ objects out of $n$.

For $X = -n < 0$ we have
$$
\frac{-n (-n-1) \cdots (-n-k+1)}{k (k-1) \cdots 1}
=
(-1)^{k} 
\frac{n (n+1) \cdots (n+k-1)}{k (k-1) \cdots 1}
=\\=
(-1)^{k} 
\frac{(n+k-1) \cdots (n+1) n}{k (k-1) \cdots 1}
=(-1)^{k} \binom{n + k - 1}{k}.
$$
(Thanks to @darij grinberg for noticing this omission.)

[A brilliant alternative proof that this is an integer is given by Tim Gowers.](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2010/09/18/are-these-the-same-proof/)

Comment: Not quite: the combinatorial interpretation only works for nonnegative integers.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, you are perfectly right, should have been fixed now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Here's the proof (not original) I like:

Let
$p_k(n) = \prod_{j=1}^k (n+j-1)$.

Then $k! | p_k(n)$.

The proof involves 
a double induction,
the outer on $k$,
the inner on $n$.

Proof.

It is true for $k=1$,
since $1 | n$.

Suppose it is true for $k$.

Consider
$p_{k+1}(n)$.

I claim that
$(k+1)! | p_{k+1}(n)$.

This is true for $n=1$,
since
$p_{k+1}(1) = (k+1)!$.

Suppose
$(k+1)! | p_{k+1}(n)$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
p_{k+1}(n+1)-p_{k+1}(n)
&=\prod_{j=1}^{k+1} (n+1+j-1)-\prod_{j=1}^{k+1} (n+j-1)\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^{k+1} (n+j)-\prod_{j=0}^{k} (n+j)\\
&=(n+k+1)\prod_{j=1}^{k} (n+j)-n\prod_{j=1}^{k} (n+j)\\
&=((n+k+1)-n)\prod_{j=1}^{k} (n+j)\\
&=(k+1)\prod_{j=1}^{k} (n+j)\\
\end{array}
$

But
(and here's the part I really like),
by the induction hypothesis on $k$,
$k! | \prod_{j=1}^{k} (n+j)$.

Therefore
$(k+1)! | (k+1)\prod_{j=1}^{k} (n+j)$.

By the induction hypothesis on $n$,
$(k+1)! |p_{k+1}(n)$.

Therefore
$(k+1)!$ divides both
$p_{k+1}(n)$
and
$(k+1)\prod_{j=1}^{k} (n+j)$,
so it divides their sum,
which is
$p_{k+1}(n+1)$.

And we are done.

Neat!

(Which, as we have just proved,
divides $p_{Neat}(n)$.)

Comment: This needs an extra induction step for negative $n$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Induction is not needed, one simply needs to note the symmetry ${-n\choose k} = (-1)^k {n+k-1\choose k}$ to cover the negative numbers.

Comment: @Winther: That works too, yes.

Answer (score 3):

This is Proposition 3.20 in my [*Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, version of 10 January 2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10) (after observing that $P_k\left(X\right) = \dfrac{1}{k!} X\left(X-1\right)\cdots\left(X-k+1\right) = \dbinom{X}{k}$).

Notice the necessity of considering the case when the numerator of the binomial coefficient (called $m$ in my notes) is negative. Most proofs require this in some way -- both the combinatorial one (since the combinatorial interpretation only handles the nonnegative case) and the induction one (unless you do a separate "induction step down"). Only the half-combinatorial-half-arithmetical proof by [Gowers](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2010/09/18/are-these-the-same-proof/) and [Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2192/) seems to avoid this issue. Of course, one can also derive the negative case from the nonnegative case: If $u$ and $v$ are two integers satisfying $u \equiv v \mod k!$, then $\dbinom{u}{k}$ is an integer if and only if $\dbinom{v}{k}$ is an integer, and therefore we can always replace an integer $u$ by some nonnegative integer $v$ that is congruent to $u$ modulo $k!$ (for example, $v$ can be set to be the remainder of $u$ modulo $k!$).